# What are some advantages to using an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, design-patterns

I was forced into a software project at work a few years ago, and was forced to learn C# quickly.  My programming background is weak (Classic ASP).

I've learned quite a bit over the years, but due to the forced nature of how I learned C#, there are a lot of basic concepts I am unclear on.

Specifically, an interface.  I understand the basics, but when writing an app, I'm having a hard time figuring out a practical use of one.  Why would one want to write an interface for their application?

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444245/how-will-i-know-when-to-create-an-interface and a search for "c# interface" for more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An interface says how something should work.  Think of it as a contract or a template.  It is key to things such as Inverson of Control or Dependancy Injection.

I use Structure Map as my IoC container.  This allows me to define an interface for all of my classes.  Where you might say

```
Widget w = new Widget();
```

I would say

```
IWidget w = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IWidget>();
```

This is very powerful in that my code isn't saying necessarily what a Widget truely is.  It just knows what a Widget can do based on the interface of IWidget.

This has some great power to it in that now that I am using an IoC container I can do a couple more nifty things.  In my unit tests where I need to use a Widget I can create a mock for Widget.  So say that my Widget does something very powerful by way of connecting to a database or a web service, my mock can simulate connecting to these resources and return to me stubbed data.  This makes my test run faster and behave in a way that is more reliable.  Because I am using StructureMap I can tell StructureMap to load the real implementation of my Widget during production use of my code and the mocked version of the Widget during testing either programatically or by configuration.

Also, because I am using an IoC container I can provide cool new features to my application such as writing three different ways to cache data.  I can have a local developer box cache using a tool such as Lucene.NET for a local cache.  I can have a development server use the .NET cache which runs great on one box.  And then I can have a third option for my production servers use a cache layer such as MemCache Win32 or Velocity.  As long as all three caching implementations conform to the same interface, their actual implementation doesn't concern me (or my code) at all.  I simply ask StructureMap to go get the current environments implementation and then go to work.

If you follow Dependency Injection at all then interfaces come in handy here also with an IoC container such as StructureMap in that I can declare the usage of a class by way of an Interface in the constructor of my class.

```
public class Widget(IWidgetRepository repository, IWidgetService service) : IWidget
{
    //do something here using my repository and service
}
```

And then when I new up an instance of Widget by way of StructureMap such as this

```
IWidget widget = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IWidget>();
```

Notice that I am not specifying the repository or service in the constructor.  StructureMap knows by way of the interfaces specified in the constructor how to go get the appropriate instances and pass them in too.  This makes very powerful and clean code!

All from the simple definition of Interfaces and some clever usage of them!

Answer (score 7):

The basic case is the "IWriter" case.

Suppose you are making a class that can write to the console, and it has all kinds of useful functions like write() and peek().

Then you would like to write a class that can write to the printer, so instead of reinventing a new class, you use the IWriter interface.

Now the cool thing about interfaces is you can write all your writing code, without knowing what is your writing target beforehand, and then can when the user decides (at runtime) weather he wants to write to the console or the printer, you just define the object as a console/printer writer and you don't need to change anything in your writing code, because they both use the same front end (interface).

Answer (score 7):

**One Simple Answer:**  Use interfaces to program against the *contract* rather than the *implementation*.

**How could that possibly help?**  Starting to use interfaces will (hopefully) get you in the habit of coupling classes more loosely.  When you code against your own concrete classes, it's easy to start poking the data structures without a strict separation of concerns.  You end up with classes which "know" everything about the other classes and things can get pretty tangled.  By limiting yourself to an interface, you only have the assurance that it fulfills the interface's contract.  It injects a sometimes helpful friction against tight coupling.

Answer (score 1):

An example. Consider an MDI application that shows reports, there's basically 2 different report types. A chart, and a grid. I need to Save these reports as PDF and I need to mail them to someone. 
The event handler for the menu the user clicks to save a report to PDF could do this:

```
void ExportPDF_Clicked(...) {
   if(currentDocument is ChartReport) {
      ChartReport r = currentDocument as ChartReport;
      r.SavePDF();
   } else if(currentDocument is GridReport) {
     GridReport r = currentDocument as GridReport;
      r.SavePDF();
   }
}
```

I'll rather make my ChartReport and GridReport implement this interface:

```
public interface Report {
  void MailTo();
  void SavePDF();
}
```

Now I can do:

```
void ExportPDF_Clicked(...) {
   Report r = currentDocument as Report;
   r.SavePDF();
}
```

Similar for other code that need to do the same operation(save it to a file,zoom in,print,etc.) on the different report types.
The above code will still work fine when I add a PivotTableReport also impelmenting Rpoert the next week.

Answer (score 1):

IOC and Dependency injection have already been mentioned above, and I would urge you to look at them.

Largely, however, interfaces allow a contract to be specified for an object that doesn't require an inheritance model.

Lets say I have class Foo, that has functions x and y and property z, and I build my code around it.

If I discover a better way to do Foo, or another sort of Foo requires implementation, I can, of course, extend a base Foo class to FooA, FooB, MyFoo etc, however that would require that all Foos have the same core functionality, or, indeed that any future Foo creators have access to the base Foo class and understand its internal workings. In C#, that would mean future Foos could not inherit from anything else but Foo, as C# does not support multiple inheritance.

It would also require me to be aware of possible future states of Foo, and try not to inhibit them in my base Foo class.

Using an interface IFoo simply states the 'contract' that a class requires to work in my Foo framework, and I don't care what any future Foo classes may inherit from or look like internally, as long as they have fn x fn y and z. It makes a framework much more flexible and open to future additions.

If, however, Foo requires a large amount of core at its base to work that would not be applicable in a contract scenario, that is when you would favour inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

good article.

An interface is a contract that guarantees to a client how a class or struct will behave.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/interfaces/article.php/c7563

This might be the clearest easiest way of explaining that I have come across:

"The answer is that they provide a fairly type-safe means of building routines that accept objects when you don't know the specific type of object that will be passed ahead of time. The only thing you know about the objects that will be passed to your routine are that they have specific members that must be present for your routine to be able to work with that object.
The best example I can give of the need for interfaces is in a team environment. Interfaces help define how different components talk to each other. By using an interface, you eliminate the possibility that a developer will misinterpret what members they must add to a type or how they will call another type that defines an interface. Without an interface, errors creep into the system and don't show up until runtime, when they are hard to find. With interfaces, errors in defining a type are caught immediately at compile time, where the cost is much less."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/kpiod/interface-oriented-design) that talks all about interfaces.  It promotes the notion that interfaces belong to the *client*, that is to say the caller.  It's a nice notion.  If you only need the thing that you're calling to implement - say - count() and get(), then you can define such an interface and let classes implement those functions.  Some classes will have many other functions, but you're only interested in those two - so you need to know less about the classes you're working with.  As long as they satisfy the contract, you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, when you inherit from an interface it forces you to implement all the methods defined in the interface. For another, this is also a good way to bring in multiple inheritance which is not supported for regular classes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer based on first principles:

A program is a universe with its own metaphysics (the reality/substance/stuff of the code) and epistemology (what you can know/believe/reason about the code). A good programming language tries to maximize the metaphysical flexibility (lets you make the stuff easily) while ensuring epistemic rigor (makes sure your universe is internally consistent).

So, think of implementation inheritance as a metaphysical building block (the stuff that makes up your little universe of code) and interface inheritance as an epistemic constraint (it allows you to believe something about your code).

You use interfaces when you only want to ensure that you can believe something. Most of the time that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned having difficulty finding a practical use for interfaces.. I've found that they come into their own when building extensible applications, for example a plugin-based app where a third-party plugin must conform to specific rules.. These rules can be defined by an interface.

You could make it so that when the plugin is loaded, it must have an Init method that takes a class that implements IServices interface.

```
public interface IServices
{
    DataManager Data { get; set; }
    LogManager Log { get; set; }
    SomeOtherManager SomeOther { get; set; }
}

public class MrPlugin
{
    public void Init(IServices services)
    {
        // Do stuff with services
    }
}
```

So.. If you have a class that implements the IServices interface, and then you instantiate it once, you can pass it to all the plugins upon initialisation and they can use whatever services you have defined in the interface.