# Returning Generic List from Generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I need to return a genericList `templateFields` as below from a generic list with code as below:

```
public interface TestData
{
    string field { get; set; }
    string fieldName { get; set; }
    string type { get; set; }
}

private static IList<T> GETCG<T>(string test, string type) where T : Program.TestData
{
    XmlNodeList extractNode = xdoc.SelectNodes(
       @".//mediaInstances/mediaInstance/properties/templateFields/templateField", manager);
    var nodees = new List<XmlNode>(extractNode.Cast<XmlNode>());
    var templateFields = nodees.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => new
    {
        field = (String)x.Attributes["userName"].Value,
        fieldName = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value
            .Substring(0, x.Attributes["name"].Value.IndexOf(':')),
        type = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value.Substring(x.Attributes["name"].Value
            .IndexOf(':') + 1, 4)                          
    }).ToList();
}

return (T)Convert.ChangeType(templateFields, typeof(T));
```

I get the following error, on the return:

> Object must implement Iconvertible.

I do understand `templateFields` doesnot implement IConvertible to use ChangeType. What's the best way of returning `templateFields`

Comment: GETCG<T> ... where T : Program.TestData... I don't think you need a generic method here.

Comment: If I'm to use a generic method, can you please advise how to solve this

Comment: Add new() to your where clause then you can select new T {... Your list will then not need converting

Comment: `select new  { .. }` returns a list of anonymous types. Have you tried `select new T { … }`? That will return a `List<T>`, and you won't need the convert statement.

Comment: @RufusL: That's exactly what Alexander has mentioned in his answer. And I'm already casting nodees to XMLNODE

Comment: I meant you *don't* need to do `nodees.Cast<XmlNode>()`, since the `nodees` items are already `XmlNode` types (you defined `nodees` as a `List<XmlNode>`).

Answer (score 1):

Add `new()` contraint to `T` and use the following codee

```
private static IList<T> GETCG<T>(string test, string type) where T : TestData, new()
{
    XmlNodeList extractNode = xdoc.SelectNodes(@".//mediaInstances/mediaInstance/properties/templateFields/templateField", manager);
    var nodees = new List<XmlNode>(extractNode.Cast<XmlNode>());
    var templateFields = nodees.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => new T() //not anonymous type but T object
    {
        field = x.Attributes["userName"].Value,
        fieldName = (string)x.Attributes["name"].Value.Substring(0, x.Attributes["name"].Value.IndexOf(':')),
        type = x.Attributes["name"].Value.Substring(x.Attributes["name"].Value.IndexOf(':') + 1, 4)

    }).ToList();

    return templateFields;
}
```

Comment: then how do I call it var returning = GETCG<?>(test,type);

Comment: ALso can you briefly explain the `new()` you added

Comment: For this to work, you will need to have a concrete type implementing `TestData` (which is an interface).

Comment: @user726720 `new()` constraint allows you instantiate `T` object within method by writing `new T()`. Otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're selecting an anonymous type when you do `select new { ... }`, and then the `Convert.ChangeType` fails because anonymous types only include `public read-only` properties, and don't implement `IConvertible`. Instead, we want to select a new `T`. But in order to do this, we also have to include a [new() constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) on `T`, which means that `T` must have a default constructor (so we can create an instance of it).

By doing this, we don't need to convert anything, as we have a `List<T>` as a result of the `Select`.

You can also reduce some code by selecting an `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` in one line, rather than creating a second variable and doing a `cast` on the first one.

Something like this should work:

```
private static IList<T> GETCG<T>(string test, string type) where T : TestData, new()
{
    IEnumerable<XmlNode> templateFieldNodes = xdoc
        .SelectNodes(".//mediaInstances/mediaInstance/properties/templateFields/templateField", 
            manager)
        .Cast<XmlNode>();

    return templateFieldNodes.Select(x => new T
    {
        field = (String)x.Attributes["userName"].Value,
        fieldName = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value
            .Substring(0, x.Attributes["name"].Value.IndexOf(':')),
        type = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value.Substring(x.Attributes["name"].Value
            .IndexOf(':') + 1, 4)
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: That's excellent, but can I know how do call it. actually I'm yet to familiarize myself with generic types and methods: var returning = GETCG<?>(test,type);

Comment: Also if you can leave me some links to get more information on generic types and methods, will be grateful

Comment: If you search for "C# generics" with your favorite search engine, you should find lots of reading, including [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/index)

Comment: Thanks for that will do some reading on it. Can you advise in the meanwhile how do I call the method: var returning = GETCG<?>(test,type);

Comment: Replace the `?` with a type that implements `TestData` and has a default constructor.

Comment: `var returning = GETCG<TestData>(test, type)`, this give me an error `TestData` must be non abstract type.

Comment: It seems you didn't read all the words in my comment. You need to pass a type that [*implements*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146020/what-does-implementing-an-interface-exactly-mean) `TestData` and *has a [default constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)*. You're passing the `TestData` interface (which really should be named `ITestData`). If you rename your interface to `ITestData`, then create a concrete class that implements it: `class TestData : ITestData`, then pass an instance of *that* class, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You declared an interface `TestData` but didn't declare any type implementing it. You cannot cast any type that just happens to have the same properties by accident to this interface. You must create a class or struct implementing it. Also, with the usual .NET naming conventions interface names start with an upper case `I` and property names have PascalCase.

With these declarations ...

```
public interface ITestData
{
    string Field { get; set; }
    string FieldName { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}

public class TestData : ITestData
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

You can write

```
private static IList<ITestData> GETCG(string test, string type)
{
    XmlNodeList extractNode = xdoc.SelectNodes(
        @".//mediaInstances/mediaInstance/properties/templateFields/templateField", manager);
    var nodees = new List<XmlNode>(extractNode.Cast<XmlNode>());
    var templateFields = nodees.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => (ITestData)new TestData {
        Field = (String)x.Attributes["userName"].Value,
        FieldName = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value
            .Substring(0, x.Attributes["name"].Value.IndexOf(':')),
        Type = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value.Substring(x.Attributes["name"].Value
            .IndexOf(':') + 1, 4)
    }).ToList();
    return templateFields;
}
```

Note that the method is not generic. To make `.ToList()` create a `IList<ITestData>`, the new data must be casted to the interface `(ITestData)new TestData { ... }`.

The question is whether you still need the interface, or if you prefer to use the class directly.

---

If you still want the method to be generic, you must tell it that `T` must have a default constructor with the `new()` constraint. And you must call the method with a concrete type. I.e., you cannot call it with the interface, since this one does not have a constructor.

```
private static IList<T> GETCG<T>(string test, string type)
    where T : ITestData, new()
{
    ...
    var templateFields = nodees.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => new T {
       ...
    }).ToList();
    return templateFields;
}
```

and call with

```
IList<TestData> var result = GETCG<TestData>("hello", "world");
```