# Queue using linked list implementation in Java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, queue

I quickly wrote a linked list class in Java. I want to write another queue class which uses the linked list. How would I achieve this in Java? I don't fully understand the implements / extends keywords... this is what my queue looks like ( for example):

```
public class Queue<T> implements LinkedList
{
    protected LinkedList<T> list;

    public Queue() {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public void add( T element) {
        list.add( element);
    }

    public T removeLast() {
        return list.removeLast();
    }   
}
```

Also note that the linked list class is also generic.
I know there are already built in classes to achieve this functionality, but I wanted to learn ( which is why I am trying to do this manually)

EDIT: Additionally, in the end, I would like to be able to say something like this:

```
Queue<String> aQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: you know about generics but not about `implements/extends` ? Seriously ?

Comment: @SoboLAN I guess he's in learning phase: "I  quickly wrote a linked list class in Java", not using the generic LinkedList.

Comment: yes - see my post "I know there are already built in classes to achieve this functionality, but I wanted to learn ( which is why I am trying to do this manually)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a behavior like `Queue<String> aQueue = new LinkedList<String>();` then your `LinkedList` must extend/implement the `Queue` class/interface. Remember that a super class can be the object reference instance of a sub class, not viceversa.

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements Queue<T> {

    class Node<T> {
        T data;
        Node<T> next;
    }

    //all your behavior here
}
```

Also, as the Java documentation states, [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is an interface and [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements it.

Note: If you want to implement a Queue using your LinkedList, you should see the code sample posted by @Tudor.

Comment: hmm i think this is exactly what i am looking for.. going to test it out quickly, thanks.

Comment: so if i declare the queue as an interface. Eg: `public interface Queue<T>{ // Methods}` those methods must not have a function body but must simply have the same name as the relevant method in the LinkedList class?

Comment: @Tim yes you're right. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866987/what-is-the-definition-of-interface-in-object-oriented-programming) and [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_07.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes in your code:

1. You are both implementing `LinkedList` (did you mean extend?) and using composition by having a `LinkedList` inside your class.
2. This piece of code will not work: `Queue<String> aQueue = new LinkedList<String>();` because according to point 1, `Queue` is either a subclass of `LinkedList` or contains a `LinkedList`, which makes your code incorrect.

In fact, the last code snippet makes very little sense. I assume that what you want to do is create a `Queue` that internally uses a linked list. In that case just use:

```
public class Queue<T>
{
    protected LinkedList<T> list;

    public Queue() {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public void add( T element) {
        list.add( element);
    }

    public T removeLast() {
        return list.removeLast();
    }   
}
```

And then:

```
Queue<String> queue = new Queue<String>();
```

Comment: ok, so what can i do to make `Queue<String> aQueue = new LinkedList<String>();` work? If I remove the `implements linkedList` from the queue class will this correct it? I am going to test it in the meanwhile... Ok i just tried it out... it says "incompatible types" ( which is why i put `implements..` in in the first place)

Comment: cool that solves the one problem... thanks :)... the reason i wanted to have that last snippet was because in my one program i create some linked lists with objects of another class... and i want to be able to copy that linked list over to a queue

Comment: @Tim: In the current form it's not possible. If you use the code I posted then there is no relationship between `LinkedList` and `Queue` so you cannot assign a `LinkedList` to a `Queue`. Furthermore, if you extend `LinkedList` it's still not correct because then `Queue` is a specialized linked list and so cannot appear to the left of the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Since Linkedlist implements queue interface we can use poll, peek methods directly....no need of extra code