# Why object can see implementation of method after upcast?

Tags: c#

Why `i` can call `Method`? It can't see the implementation of the `Method`, only declaration, isn't it? Is it upcast and boxing at the same time.. or not?

```
interface IB
{
    void Method();
}

struct A : IB
{
    public void Method() { Console.WriteLine("1"); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a;
        a.Method();
        IB i = a;   // boxing.. and upcast?
        i.Method(); // why it works? It looks like call of declaration
    }
}
```

Result of work:

> 1
>
> 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866987/what-is-the-definition-of-interface-in-object-oriented-programming

Comment: @Othello.netdev, Please before sending a single link, describe briefly about that link.

Comment: Sorry, i've posted one good article where interface and are well explained.

Comment: First of all this is not a boxing example. This is polymorphism example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign your object to the instance of your interface `i` you are simply hiding anything else in the `a` object that doesnt match the interface definition.

Instead lets assume your struct was

```
struct A : IB
{
    public void Method() { Console.WriteLine("1"); }   // Method defined in interface IB. 

    public void Method2() { Console.WriteLine("2"); }  // Method only in A
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a;
        a.Method();
        a.Method2();  // This works. 
        IB i = a;
        i.Method();
        i.Method2();// This fails to compile because Method2 isnt defined in the interface. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating an instance of A, then calling the method in A, and then declaring IB(i) to be the instance of A and again calling its method

Answer (score 1):

The instance of class `A` implements interface `IB`, that is to say, any instance of class `A` is also type of interface `IB`, so it is perfectly legitimate to assign object of `A` to `IB`. No casting. No boxing. And yes, as @CathalMF said, you will only be able to call what is there in `IB` interface from this object.