# How to implement interface AND extend a thread in an abstract class in java

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, abstract

I am trying to fulfil the requirements of the homework... "Include at least one interface that contains at least one method that implementing classes must implement."

When I try to instantiate the interface it says it cannot instantiate the interface.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried several ways to make it work.

```
//main class
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ford mustang = new Ford("Mustang", 135, 125);
        Chevrolet camero = new Chevrolet("Camero", 202, 100);
        Dodge challenger = new Dodge("Challenger", 203, 75);        

        Nitrous nitro = new Nitrous();//problem code

        mustang.start();
        camero.start();
        challenger.start();
    }

}

//Abstract class
public abstract class Vehicle extends Thread implements Nitrous {

    private String model;
    private int speed;
    private int boost;

    public Vehicle(String model, int speed, int boost) {
        this.model = model;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.boost = boost;
    }

    public String getmodel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setmodel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getspeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setspeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getboost() {
        return boost;
    }

    public void setboost(int boost) {
        this.boost = boost;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            go();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void go() throws InterruptedException {
        int trackLength = 5000;
        int checkPointPassed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < trackLength; i += (speed + boost)) {
            if (checkPointPassed * 1000 < i) {
                checkPointPassed++;
                System.out.println("The " + this.model + " has passed check point " + checkPointPassed);
//              System.out.println(nos);
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }

}

//subclass one of three
public class Ford extends Vehicle {

    public Ford (String model, int speed, int boost) {

        super(model, speed, boost); 

    }

    @Override
    public void nos() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("The cars have Nitro!");
    }

}

public class Chevrolet extends Vehicle{

    public Chevrolet(String model, int speed, int boost) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub.
        super(model, speed, boost);
    }

    @Override
    public void nos() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("The cars have Nitro!");
    }

}

public class Dodge extends Vehicle{

    public Dodge(String model, int speed, int boost) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(model, speed, boost);
    }

    @Override
    public void nos() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("The cars have Nitro!");
    }

}

//Interface

public interface Nitrous {

    public void nos();
}
```

It is a race with three vehicles that have a nitrous boost.  I have chosen to make the Nitrous the interface.  You can see in my code where I have tried different ways to make it work and none have been successful.  I don't even know if I am close or way off with how to do this.

Comment: There's no reason to instantiate the interface; all three vehicles implement (override) the interface so that is all you need.

Comment: You may want to make the `nos` function more interesting by defining it as `boolean hasNitro`, have each vehicle subclass decide what it returns and use the `hasNitro` in the Vehicle `go`.

Comment: Ohhh, nifty idea Andy...I might try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interface only provides a blueprint on what a specific class *can* do that implements it. To give you a concrete example, consider the interface `Fruit`.

```
public interface Fruit {

  void eat();

}
```

Now, it does not make sense to instantiate an interface, since it is only an abstraction. However, it would make sense to actually create an object of the class `Banana` or `Apple`. And since these are all fruits, you can eat them.

```
for (Fruit f : fruits) {
  f.eat();
}
```

Since your `Vehicle` class implements `Nitrous`, all of its subclasses can be assigned to that specific type as well, and they fulfill its contract, which is `nos()`.

```
Ford mustang = new Ford("Mustang", 135, 125);

Nitrous asNitrous = mustang; // works
mustang.nos(); // works
```

Related: [What is the definition of an interface in object oriented programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866987/what-is-the-definition-of-interface-in-object-oriented-programming)