# Is Facade design pattern is implementation of abstraction characteristic of oops?

Tags: design-patterns, abstraction, facade

According to the definition of Façade, It provides simplifies interface to use complex subsystems. will it be right to say that Façade is an implementation of Abstraction characteristics of OOPS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Façade is certainly an example of Abstraction. In fact, anywhere that the GoF patterns use the word [interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866987/what-is-the-definition-of-interface-in-object-oriented-programming), what they mean is *abstraction*.

Abstraction is the elimination of (unnecessary) detail in order to highlight general points. We can achieve a range of abstraction by removing more or less detail; and we refer to design with more detail removed as being at a high level of abstraction, whereas design with less detail removed is at a lower level of abstraction.

Façade is intended to provide a high level of abstraction by removing the details of numerous (less abstract) subsystems.

Comment: Thanks Jack, for simplifying the understanding for me. Now I would always think with this point of view also whether we are at the stage of lower level of abstraction or higher level of abstraction.