# Interfaces — What's the point?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

The reason for interfaces truly eludes me. From what I understand, it is kind of a work around for the non-existent multi-inheritance which doesn't exist in C# (or so I was told).

All I see is, you predefine some members and functions, which then have to be re-defined in the class again. Thus making the interface redundant. It just feels like syntactic… well, junk to me (Please no offense meant. Junk as in useless stuff).

In the example given below taken from a different C# interfaces thread on stack overflow, I would just create a base class called Pizza instead of an interface.

easy example (taken from a different stack overflow contribution)

```
public interface IPizza
{
    public void Order();
}

public class PepperoniPizza : IPizza
{
    public void Order()
    {
        //Order Pepperoni pizza
    }
}

public class HawaiiPizza : IPizza
{
    public void Order()
    {
        //Order HawaiiPizza
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling there are duplicates of this question here on SO, but they all seem to just explain the contract part of an interface so I'm not sure they apply.

Comment: trying to be a nice and tidy user, I tend to look for my answer first in various forums before I post something. Unfortunately, most of them started at a later stage and the rest didn't help. I was already struggling with the basic "Why do it?" as it seemed to me like unnecessary overcomplicating it.

Btw. Thanks to all for the very quick answers. I have to digest them all first, but I think I have now a reasonably good idea of the point of them. It seems I have always looked at it from a different angle. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I just want to state that interfaces is hard to understand. You need to make a great effort to master them. If you have the time you should read this book: [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/). It will also introduce you to lots of related ideas. Also note that Python and C# is pretty different. C# is statically typed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971326/the-point-of-an-interface/3971580#3971580

Comment: Also interfaces help to establish inheritance like for `struct` types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24436493/1286942

Comment: Hmm, the OP was asking "From what I understand, interface is kind of a work around for the non-existent multi-inheritance which doesn't exist in C#. (Other than that, in the quoted textbook pizza example) I would just use a base class instead of an interface". And then most answers either gave an example that can be implemented by a (abstract) base class, or gave an example to show how interface is necessary for multi-inheritance scenario. Those answers are all good, but aren't they just reiterating something the OP already know? No wonder OP ended up choosing an answer without examples. LOL

Comment: I like to think of them like the __declspec(dllexport) declarations in the header file that you had create for making DLLs in C/C++, but whereas the exports were essential for the DLL to work, they are not that essential for classes, as the header would do the same. So I suppose its c# doing c++ things in a different way (wrapping it all up so you don't see the extraneous code) and taking credit for it (as usual!).

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The point is that the interface represents a *contract*. A set of public methods any implementing class has to have. Technically, the interface only governs syntax, i.e. what methods are there,  what arguments they get and what they return. Usually they encapsulate semantics as well, although that only by documentation.

You can then have different implementations of an interface and swap them out at will. In your example, since every pizza instance is an `IPizza` you can use `IPizza` wherever you handle an instance of an unknown pizza type. Any instance whose type inherits from `IPizza` is guaranteed to be orderable, as it has an `Order()` method.

Python is not statically-typed, therefore types are kept and looked up at runtime. So you can try calling an `Order()` method on any object. The runtime is happy as long as the object has such a method and probably just shrugs and says »Meh.« if it doesn't. Not so in C#. The compiler is responsible for making the correct calls and if it just has some random `object` the compiler doesn't know yet whether the instance during runtime will have that method. From the compiler's point of view it's invalid since it cannot verify it. (You can do such things with reflection or the `dynamic` keyword, but that's going a bit far right now, I guess.)

Also note that an interface in the usual sense does not necessarily have to be a C# `interface`, it could be an abstract class as well or even a normal class (which can come in handy if all subclasses need to share some common code – in most cases, however, `interface` suffices).

Comment: +1, although I wouldn't say that the interface (in sense of a contract) can be an abstract or a normal class.

Comment: I would add that you can't expect to understand interfaces in a couple of minutes. I think it is not reasonable to understand interfaces if you don't have years of object oriented programming experience. You may add some links to books. I would suggest: [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) which is really how deep the rabit hole goes, not just a gentle introduction.

Comment: Ah, there's the problem of me having no clue of DI. But I guess the main problem of the asker was why they are needed when in Python it all works without. That's what the largest paragraph of my answer tried to provide. I don't think it's necessary to dig in every pattern and practice that uses interfaces here.

Comment: Well, then your question becomes: "Why use statically typed languages when dynamically typed languages are easier to program in?". Although I'm not the expert to answer that question, I can venture to say that performance is the deciding issue. When a call to a python object is made, the process must decide during run time whether that object has a method called "Order", whereas if you make the call to a C# object, it's already established that it implements that method, and the call can be made to such an such address.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu: Beyond that, with a statically-typed object if one knows `foo` implements `IWidget`, then a programmer seeing a call to `foo.woozle()` can look at the documentation for `IWidget` and know *what that method is supposed to do*.  The programmer might have no way of knowing where the code for the actual implementation will come from, but any type which abides by the `IWidget` interface contract will implement `foo` in a manner consistent with that contract.  In a dynamic language, by contrast, there would be no clear reference point for what `foo.woozle()` should mean.

Comment: For those who wanders why `Python`. OP [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6802573/1) he knows python, but this was edited out from question. Now we indeed have very good canonical C# question and not so good (not everybody knows Python) answer.

Answer (score 503):

No one has really explained in plain terms how interfaces are useful, so I'm going to give it a shot (and steal an idea from Shamim's answer a bit).

Lets take the idea of a pizza ordering service.  You can have multiple types of pizzas and a common action for each pizza is preparing the order in the system.  Each pizza **has to be prepared** but each pizza **is prepared differently**.  For example, when a stuffed crust pizza is ordered the system probably has to verify certain ingredients are available at the restaurant and set those aside that aren't needed for deep dish pizzas.

When writing this in code, technically you could just do

```
public class Pizza
{
    public void Prepare(PizzaType tp)
    {
        switch (tp)
        {
            case PizzaType.StuffedCrust:
                // prepare stuffed crust ingredients in system
                break;
                
            case PizzaType.DeepDish:
                // prepare deep dish ingredients in system
                break;
                
            //.... etc.
        }
    }
}
```

However, deep dish pizzas (in C# terms) may require different properties to be set in the `Prepare()` method than stuffed crust, and thus you end up with a lot of optional properties, and the class doesn't scale well (what if you add new pizza types).

The proper way to solve this is to use interface.  The interface declares that all Pizzas can be prepared, but each pizza can be prepared differently.  So if you have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IPizza
{
    void Prepare();
}

public class StuffedCrustPizza : IPizza
{
    public void Prepare()
    {
        // Set settings in system for stuffed crust preparations
    }
}

public class DeepDishPizza : IPizza
{
    public void Prepare()
    {
        // Set settings in system for deep dish preparations
    }
}
```

Now your order handling code does not need to know exactly what types of pizzas were ordered in order to handle the ingredients.  It just has:

```
public PreparePizzas(IList<IPizza> pizzas)
{
    foreach (IPizza pizza in pizzas)
        pizza.Prepare();
}
```

Even though each type of pizza is prepared differently, this part of the code doesn't have to care what type of pizza we are dealing with, it just knows that it's being called for pizzas and therefore each call to `Prepare` will automatically prepare each pizza correctly based on its type, even if the collection has multiple types of pizzas.

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps amend it to clarify why an interface in this case is better than just using an abstract class (for such a simple example, an abstract class may indeed be better?)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This example could have just as easily been done with a base class and an abstract method, which is exactly what the original question pointed out.

Comment: This use of interfaces is no different then using an abstract base class. What is the advantage?

Comment: Interfaces don't really come into their right until you have a lot of them going around. You can only inherit from a single class, abstract or not, but you can implement as many different interfaces in a single class as you like. Suddenly you don't need a door in a door frame; anything that is IOpenable will do, be it a door, a window, a letterbox, you name it.

Comment: This could have been done with an abstract `BasePizza` class so I don't think I understand why we should use interface instead of abstract class approach. This answer here explains it better: 2 classes without a strict is-a relationship but with common behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface?rq=1

Comment: Still don't understand why we should use interfaces. Especially the second part/example of the code. I would of just used an abstract class so it can call the Prepare() method regardless of what pizza are needed/created. So confused

Answer (score 155):

For me, when starting out, the point to these only became clear when you stop looking at them as things to make your code easier/faster to write - this is not their purpose. They have a number of uses:

(This is going to lose the pizza analogy, as it's not very easy to visualise a use of this)

Say you are making a simple game on screen and It will have creatures with which you interact.

**A: They can make your code easier to maintain in the future by introducing a loose coupling between your front end and your back end implementation.**

You could write this to start with, as there are only going to be trolls:

```
// This is our back-end implementation of a troll
class Troll
{
    void Walk(int distance)
    {
        //Implementation here
    }
}
```

Front end:

```
function SpawnCreature()
{
    Troll aTroll = new Troll();
    
    aTroll.Walk(1);
}
```

Two weeks down the line, marketing decide you also need Orcs, as they read about them on twitter, so you would have to do something like:

```
class Orc
{
    void Walk(int distance)
    {
        //Implementation (orcs are faster than trolls)
    }
}
```

Front end:

```
void SpawnCreature(creatureType)
{
    switch(creatureType)
    {
         case Orc:

           Orc anOrc = new Orc();
           anORc.Walk();

          case Troll:

            Troll aTroll = new Troll();
             aTroll.Walk();
    }
}
```

And you can see how this starts to get messy.  You could use an interface here so that your front end would be written once and (here's the important bit) tested, and you can then plug in further back end items as required:

```
interface ICreature
{
    void Walk(int distance)
}

public class Troll : ICreature
public class Orc : ICreature 

//etc
```

Front end is then:

```
void SpawnCreature(creatureType)
{
    ICreature creature;

    switch(creatureType)
    {
         case Orc:

           creature = new Orc();

          case Troll:

            creature = new Troll();
    }

    creature.Walk();
}
```

The front end now only cares about the interface ICreature - it's not bothered about the internal implementation of a troll or an orc, but only on the fact that they implement ICreature.

An important point to note when looking at this from this point of view is that you could also easily have used an abstract creature class, and from this perspective, this has the **same** effect.

And you could extract the creation out to a factory:

```
public class CreatureFactory {

 public ICreature GetCreature(creatureType)
 {
    ICreature creature;

    switch(creatureType)
    {
         case Orc:

           creature = new Orc();

          case Troll:

            creature = new Troll();
    }

    return creature;
  }
}
```

And our front end would then become:

```
CreatureFactory _factory;

void SpawnCreature(creatureType)
{
    ICreature creature = _factory.GetCreature(creatureType);

    creature.Walk();
}
```

The front end now does not even have to have a reference to the library where Troll and Orc are implemented (providing the factory is in a separate library) - it need know nothing about them whatsoever.

**B: Say you have functionality that only some creatures will have in your otherwise homogenous data structure**, e.g.

```
interface ICanTurnToStone
{
   void TurnToStone();
}

public class Troll: ICreature, ICanTurnToStone
```

Front end could then be:

```
void SpawnCreatureInSunlight(creatureType)
{
    ICreature creature = _factory.GetCreature(creatureType);

    creature.Walk();

    if (creature is ICanTurnToStone)
    {
       (ICanTurnToStone)creature.TurnToStone();
    }
}
```

**C: Usage for dependency injection**

Most dependency injection frameworks work when there is a very loose coupling between the front end code and the back end implementation.  If we take our factory example above and have our factory implement an interface:

```
public interface ICreatureFactory {
     ICreature GetCreature(string creatureType);
}
```

Our front end could then have this injected (e.g an MVC API controller) through the constructor (typically):

```
public class CreatureController : Controller {

   private readonly ICreatureFactory _factory;

   public CreatureController(ICreatureFactory factory) {
     _factory = factory;
   }

   public HttpResponseMessage TurnToStone(string creatureType) {

       ICreature creature = _factory.GetCreature(creatureType);
   
       creature.TurnToStone();

       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }
}
```

With our DI framework (e.g. Ninject or Autofac), we can set them up so that at runtime a instance of CreatureFactory will be created whenever an ICreatureFactory is needed in an constructor - this makes our code nice and simple.

It also means that when we write a unit test for our controller, we can provide a mocked ICreatureFactory (e.g. if the concrete implementation required DB access, we don't want our unit tests dependent on that) and easily test the code in our controller.

**D: There are other uses e.g. you have two projects A and B that for 'legacy' reasons are not well structured, and A has a reference to B.**

You then find functionality in B that needs to call a method already in A. You can't do it using concrete implementations as you get a circular reference.

You can have an interface declared in B that the class in A then implements. Your method in B can be passed an instance of a class that implements the interface with no problem, even though the concrete object is of a type in A.

Comment: Isn't it annoying when you find an answer that was trying to say what you were, but does it a lot better - http://stackoverflow.com/a/93998/117215

Comment: The good news is now its a dead page and yours isn't :). Good example!

Comment: Your C discussion lost me a bit. But, I like your A and B discussions because they both essentially explain how interfaces can be used to provide common kinds of functionality across multiple classes. The area of interfaces that is still fuzzy to me is how interfaces are used for looser coupling. Perhaps that is what your C discussion was addressing? If so, I guess I need a more detailed example :)

Comment: It seems to me in your example that ICreature would be better suited to being an abstract base class (Creature?) for the Troll and Orc. Then any common logic between creatures could be implemented there. Which means you don't need the ICreature interface at all...

Comment: @Skarsnik - quite, which is what this note is about: "An important point to note when looking at this from this point of view is that you could also easily have used an abstract creature class, and from this perspective, this has the same effect."

Answer (score 43):

Examples above don't make much sense. You could accomplish all above examples using classes (abstract class if you want it to behave only as a *contract*):

```
public abstract class Food {
    public abstract void Prepare();
}

public class Pizza : Food  {
    public override void Prepare() { /* Prepare pizza */ }
}

public class Burger : Food  {
    public override void Prepare() { /* Prepare Burger */ }
}
```

You get the same behavior as with interface. You can create a `List<Food>` and iterate that w/o knowing what class sits on top.

More adequate example would be multiple inheritance:

```
public abstract class MenuItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void BringToTable();
}

// Notice Soda only inherits from MenuItem
public class Soda : MenuItem {
    public override void BringToTable() { /* Bring soda to table */ }
}


// All food needs to be cooked (real food) so we add this
// feature to all food menu items
public interface IFood {
    void Cook();
}

public class Pizza : MenuItem, IFood {
    public override void BringToTable() { /* Bring pizza to table */ }
    public void Cook() { /* Cook Pizza */ }
}

public class Burger : MenuItem, IFood {
    public override void BringToTable() { /* Bring burger to table */ }
    public void Cook() { /* Cook Burger */ }
}
```

Then you can use all of them as `MenuItem` and don't care about how they handle each method call.

```
public class Waiter {
    public void TakeOrder(IEnumerable<MenuItem> order) 
    {
        // Cook first
        // (all except soda because soda is not IFood)
        foreach (var food in order.OfType<IFood>())
            food.Cook();

        // Bring them all to the table
        // (everything, including soda, pizza and burger because they're all menu items)
        foreach (var menuItem in order)
            menuItem.BringToTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to scroll all the way down here to find an answer that actually answers the question "why not just use a abstract class instead of an interface?". It seems it really is to only handle c#'s lack of multiple inheritance.

Comment: Yes this is the best explanation for me. The only one that clearly explain why interface can be more useful than an abstract class. (i.e: a pizza is a MenuItem AND is also Food while with an abstract class it can only be one or another but not both)

Answer (score 43):

## Simple Explanation with analogy

#### No interface (Example 1):

[image: Example 1: without an interface]

#### No interface (Example 2):

[image: Example 2: without an interface]

### With an interface:

[image: Example 3: The benefits of Using an Interface]

#### The Problem to Solve: What is the purpose of polymorphism?

Analogy: So I'm a foreperson on a construction site. I don't know which tradesperson is going to walk in. But I tell them what to do.

1. If it's a carpenter I say: `build wooden scaffolding`.
2. If it's a plumber, I say: `Set up the pipes`
3. If it's a <strike>BJP</strike> government bureaucrat, I say, `three bags full of cash, sir.`

The problem with the above approach is that I have to: (i) know who's walking in that door, and depending on who it is, I have to tell them what to do. This typically makes code harder to maintain  or more error prone.

#### The implications of knowing what to do:

- This means if the carpenter's code changes from: `BuildScaffolding()` to `BuildScaffold()` (i.e. a slight name change) then I will have to also change the calling class (i.e. the `Foreperson` class) as well - you'll have to make ***two*** changes to the code instead of (basically) just one. With polymorphism you (basically) only need to make one change to achieve the same result.
- Secondly you won't have to constantly ask: who are you? ok do this...who are you? ok do that.....polymorphism - it DRYs that code, and is very effective in certain situations:
- with polymorphism you can easily add additional classes of tradespeople without changing any existing code. (i.e. the second of the SOLID design principles: Open-close principle).

## The solution

Imagine a scenario where, no matter who walks in the door, I can say: "Work()" and they do their respect jobs that they specialise in:  the plumber would deal with pipes, and the electrician would deal with wires, and a bureaucrat could specialise in extracting bribes and making double work for everyone else.

So instead of this:

```
if(electrician) then  electrician.FixCablesAndElectricity() 

if(plumber) then plumber.IncreaseWaterPressureAndFixLeaks() 

if(keralaCustoms) then keralaCustoms.askForBribes()
```

I can do something like this:

```
ITradesman tradie = Tradesman.Factory(); // in reality i know it's a plumber, but in the real world you won't know who's on the other side of the tradie assignment.

tradie.Work(); // and then tradie will do the work of a plumber, or electrician etc. depending on what type of tradesman he is. The foreman doesn't need to know anything, apart from telling the anonymous tradie to get to Work()!!
```

#### What's the benefit?

The benefit is that if the specific job requirements of the carpenter etc change, then the foreperson won't need to change his code - he doesn't need to know or care. All that matters is that the carpenter knows what is meant by Work(). Secondly, if a new type of construction worker comes onto the job site, then all the foreman cares for is if the construction worker (.e.g Welder, Glazier, Tiler etc.) can get some Work() done.

## Summary

An interface allows you to get the person to do the work they are assigned to, without you having the knowledge of exactly who they are or the specifics of what they can do. This allows you to easily add new types (of trade), and allows you to effectively changing your code and minimising any cascading effects.

**Confused?** Post a comment so i can fix it up.

Comment: Expanding on the example of a foreman not needing to know the specifics and the mention of SOLID principles, would this also clear the Dependacy Inversion principle, as the foreman doesn't know what "GetToWork()" needs doing, but know's it needs "GetToWork()" done?

PS The foreman sure sounds like a few managers I worked for :)

Comment: @ShaunnyBwoy Yes that is absolutely correct. The forepersons still needs to order know that "GetToWork" needs doing, but the specifics of what that actually entails - he won't know. and he cannot know. I used this analogy to represent real life. When someone builds a house they typically employ a builder and say: `Work()` - you know that 'Work"  is necessary, but the specifics (e.g. conducting measurements, bribing council workers for permits etc) are something you cannot know, and probably do not care about. Those implementation details are left to the builder. makes changing code x10 easier.

Answer (score 35):

Here are your examples reexplained:

```
public interface IFood // not Pizza
{
    public void Prepare();

}

public class Pizza : IFood
{
    public void Prepare() // Not order for explanations sake
    {
        //Prepare Pizza
    }
}

public class Burger : IFood
{
    public void Prepare()
    {
        //Prepare Burger
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In the absence of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) as you can use it in Python, C# relies on interfaces to provide abstractions. If the dependencies of a class were all concrete types, you could not pass in any other type - using interfaces you can pass in any type that implements the interface.

Comment: +1 That's right, if you have duck typing, you don't need interfaces. But they do enforce stronger type safety.

Answer (score 12):

The Pizza example is bad because you should be using an abstract class that handles the ordering, and the pizzas should just override the pizza type, for example.

You use interfaces when you have a shared property, but your classes inherit from different places, or when you don't have any common code you could use. For instance, this is used things that can be disposed `IDisposable`, you know it will be disposed, you just don't know what will happen when it's disposed.

An interface is just a contract that tells you some things an object can do, what parameters and what return types to expect.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the case where you don't control or own the base classes.

Take visual controls for instance, in .NET for Winforms they all inherit from the base class Control, that is completely defined in the .NET framework.

Let's assume you're in the business of creating custom controls. You want to build new buttons, textboxes, listviews, grids, whatnot and you'd like them all to have certain features unique to your set of controls.

For instance you might want a common way to handle theming, or a common way to handle localization.

In this case you can't "just create a base class" because if you do that, you have to reimplement *everything* that relates to controls.

Instead you will descend from Button, TextBox, ListView, GridView, etc. and add your code.

But this poses a problem, how can you now identify which controls are "yours", how can you build some code that says "for all the controls on the form that are mine, set the theme to X".

Enter interfaces.

Interfaces are a way to look at an object, to determine that the object adheres to a certain contract.

You would create "YourButton", descend from Button, and add support for all the interfaces you need.

This would allow you to write code like the following:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is IMyThemableControl)
        ((IMyThemableControl)ctrl).SetTheme(newTheme);
}
```

This would not be possible without interfaces, instead you would have to write code like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is MyThemableButton)
        ((MyThemableButton)ctrl).SetTheme(newTheme);
    else if (ctrl is MyThemableTextBox)
        ((MyThemableTextBox)ctrl).SetTheme(newTheme);
    else if (ctrl is MyThemableGridView)
        ((MyThemableGridView)ctrl).SetTheme(newTheme);
    else ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know, you shouldn't use "is" and then cast, leave that aside.

Comment: *sigh* I know, but that's incidental here.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, you could ( and probably would ) just define a Pizza base class and inherit from them. However, there are two reasons where Interfaces allow you to do things that cannot be achieved in other ways:

1. A class can implement multiple interfaces. It just defines features that the class must have. Implementing a range of interfaces means that a class can fulfil multiple functions in different places.
2. An interface can be defined in a hogher scope than the class or the caller. This means that you can separate the functionality, separate the project dependency, and keep the functionality in one project or class, and the implementation of this elsewhere.

One implication of 2 is that you can change the class that is being used, just requiring that it implements the appropriate interface.

Answer (score 6):

Consider you can't use multiple inheritance in C#, and then look at your question again.

Answer (score 5):

Interface = contract, used for [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) (see [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29)).

Answer (score 5):

I did a search for the word "composition" on this page and didn't see it once.  This answer is very much in addition to the answers aforementioned.

One of the absolutely crucial reasons for using interfaces in an Object Oriented Project is that they allow you to favour composition over inheritance.  By implementing interfaces you can decouple your implementations from the various algorithms you are applying to them.

This superb "Decorator Pattern" tutorial by Derek Banas (which - funnily enough - also uses pizza as an example) is a worthwhile illustration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j40kRwSm4VE

Answer (score 4):

An interface is really a contract that the implementing classes must follow, it is in fact the base for pretty much every design pattern I know.

In your example, the interface is created because then anything that **IS A** Pizza, which means implements the Pizza interface, is guaranteed to have implemented

```
public void Order();
```

After your mentioned code you could have something like this:

```
public void orderMyPizza(IPizza myPizza) {
//This will always work, because everyone MUST implement order
      myPizza.order();
}
```

This way you are using polymorphism and all you care is that your objects respond to order().

Answer (score 4):

If I am working on an API to draw shapes, I may want to use DirectX or graphic calls, or OpenGL.  So, I will create an interface, which will abstract my implementation from what you call.

So you call a factory method: `MyInterface i = MyGraphics.getInstance()`.  Then, you have a contract, so you know what functions you can expect in `MyInterface`.  So, you can call `i.drawRectangle` or `i.drawCube` and know that if you swap one library out for another, that the functions are supported.

This becomes more important if you are using Dependency Injection, as then you can, in an XML file, swap implementations out.

So, you may have one crypto library that can be exported that is for general use, and another that is for sale only to American companies, and the difference is in that you change a config file, and the rest of the program isn't changed.

This is used a great deal with collections in .NET, as you should just use, for example, `List` variables, and don't worry whether it was an ArrayList or LinkedList.

As long as you code to the interface then the developer can change the actual implementation and the rest of the program is left unchanged.

This is also useful when unit testing, as you can mock out entire interfaces, so, I don't have to go to a database, but to a mocked out implementation that just returns static data, so I can test my method without worrying if the database is down for maintenance or not.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces are for applying connection between different classes. for example, you have a class for car and a tree;

```
public class Car { ... }

public class Tree { ... }
```

you want to add a burnable functionality for both classes. But each class have their own ways to burn. so you simply make;

```
public class Car : IBurnable
{
public void Burn() { ... }
}

public class Tree : IBurnable
{
public void Burn() { ... }
}
```

Comment: The question that haunts me in examples like this is: Why does this help? Can I now pass the argument of type IBurnable to a method and all classes with the IBurnable interface can be handled? Same as the Pizza example I found. It is nice that you can do this, but I do not see the benefit, as such. Could you either extend the example (because I am really thick at the moment) or give an example that wouldn't work with it (again, because I feel really thick at the moment). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Agree. Interface = "Can do". Class/Abstract Calss = "Is A"

Answer (score 4):

You will get interfaces, when you will need them :) You can study examples, but you need the Aha! effect to really get them.

Now that you know what interfaces are, just code without them. Sooner or later you will run into a problem, where the use of interfaces will be the most natural thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that not many posts contain the one most important reason for an interface: **Design Patterns**. It's the bigger picture into using contracts, and although it's a syntax decoration to machine code (to be honest, the compiler probably just ignores them), abstraction and interfaces are pivotal for OOP, human understanding, and complex system architectures.

Let's expand the pizza analogy to say a full fledge 3 course meal. We'll still have the core `Prepare()` interface for all our food categories, but we'd also have abstract declarations for course selections (starter, main, dessert), and differing properties for food types (savoury/sweet, vegetarian/non-vegetarian, gluten free etc).

Based on these specifications, we could implement the *Abstract Factory* pattern to conceptualise the whole process, but use interfaces to ensure that only the foundations were concrete. Everything else could become flexible or encourage polymorphism, yet maintain encapsulation between the different classes of `Course` that implement the `ICourse` interface.

If I had more time, I'd like to draw up a full example of this, or someone can extend this for me, but in summary, a C# interface would be the best tool in designing this type of system.

Comment: This answer deserves more points! Interfaces shine when used in designed patterns e.g. The State Pattern. See https://plus.google.com/+ZoranHorvat-Programming for additional information

Answer (score 4):

Here's an interface for objects that have a rectangular shape:

```
interface IRectangular
{
    Int32 Width();
    Int32 Height();
}
```

All it demands is that you implement ways to access the width and height of the object.

Now let's define a method that will work on any object that is `IRectangular`:

```
static class Utils
{
    public static Int32 Area(IRectangular rect)
    {
        return rect.Width() * rect.Height();
    }
}
```

That will return the area of any rectangular object.

Let's implement a class `SwimmingPool` that is rectangular:

```
class SwimmingPool : IRectangular
{
    int width;
    int height;

    public SwimmingPool(int w, int h)
    { width = w; height = h; }

    public int Width() { return width; }
    public int Height() { return height; }
}
```

And another class `House` that is also rectangular:

```
class House : IRectangular
{
    int width;
    int height;

    public House(int w, int h)
    { width = w; height = h; }

    public int Width() { return width; }
    public int Height() { return height; }
}
```

Given that, you can call the `Area` method on houses or swimming-pools:

```
var house = new House(2, 3);

var pool = new SwimmingPool(3, 4);

Console.WriteLine(Utils.Area(house));
Console.WriteLine(Utils.Area(pool));
```

In this way, your classes can "inherit" behavior (static-methods) from any number of interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

#### *What ?*

Interfaces are basically a contract that all the classes *implementing* the Interface should follow. They looks like a class but has no implementation.

In `C#` Interface names by convention is defined by Prefixing an 'I' so if you want to have an interface called shapes, you would declare it as `IShapes`

#### *Now Why ?*

#### **`Improves code re-usability`**

Lets say you want to draw `Circle`, `Triangle.`  
You can group them together and call them `Shapes`and have methods to draw `Circle` and `Triangle`
But having concrete implementation would be a bad idea because tomorrow you might decide to have 2 more `Shapes` `Rectangle` & `Square`. Now when you add them there is a great chance that you might break other parts of your code.

*With Interface you isolate the different implementation from the Contract*

---

*Live Scenario Day 1*

You were asked to create an App to Draw Circle and Triangle

```
interface IShapes
{
   void DrawShape();
   
 }

class Circle : IShapes
{
    
    public void DrawShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation to Draw a Circle");
    }
}

Class Triangle: IShapes
{
     public void DrawShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation to draw a Triangle");
    }
}
```

```
static void Main()
{
     List <IShapes> shapes = new List<IShapes>();
        shapes.Add(new Circle());
        shapes.Add(new Triangle());

        foreach(var shape in shapes)
        {
            shape.DrawShape();
        }
}
```

*Live Scenario Day 2*

If you were asked add `Square` and `Rectangle` to it, all you have to do is create the implentation for it in `class Square: IShapes` and in `Main` add to list `shapes.Add(new Square());`

Comment: Why are you adding an answer to a 6 year old question with dozens of other answers upvoted hundreds of times? There's nothing here that hasn't already been said.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, yes, I thought so, but then I was thinking this example and the way its explained will help related to some body better than the others.

Answer (score 3):

An interface defines a contract between the provider of a certain functionality and the correspondig consumers. It decouples the implementation from the contract (interface). You should have a look at object oriented architecture and design. You may want to start with wikipedia: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing))

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of good answers here but I would like to try from a slightlt different perspective.

You may be familiar with the SOLID principles of object oriented design. In summary:

S - Single Responsibility Principle
O - Open/Closed Principle
L - Liskov Substitution Principle
I - Interface Segregation Principle
D - Dependency Inversion Principle

Following the SOLID principles helps to produce code that is clean, well factored, cohesive and loosely coupled. Given that:

> "Dependency management is the key challenge in software at every scale" (Donald Knuth)

then anything that helps with dependency management is a big win. Interfaces and the Dependency Inversion Principle really help to decouple code from dependencies on concrete classes, so code can be written and reasoned about in terms of *behaviours* rather than implementations. This helps to break the code into components which can be composed at runtime rather than compile time and also means those components can be quite easily plugged in and out without having to alter the rest of the code.

Interfaces help in particular with the Dependency Inversion Principle, where code can be componentized into a collection of services, with each service being described by an interface. Services can then be "injected" into classes at runtime by passing them in as a constructor parameter. This technique really becomes critical if you start to write unit tests and use test driven development. Try it! You will quickly understand how interfaces help to break apart the code into manageable chunks that can be individually tested in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Soo many answers!
Giving my best shot. hehe.

So to begin, yes you could have used a concrete base and derived class here. In that case, you would have to do an empty or useless implementation for the *Prepare* method in the base class also making this method `virtual` and then the derived classes would override this *Prepare* method for themselves. This case, the implementation of *Prepare* in Base class is useless.

The reason why you chose to use an `Interface` is because you had to **define a contract, not an implementation**.

There is a `IPizza` type and it provides a functionality to *Prepare*. This is contract. How it is prepared is the implementation and it is *not your lookout*. It is responsibility of the various `Pizza` implementations.
An `interface` or an `abstract` class is preferred here over a concrete base class because you had to create an abstraction, i.e., the Prepare method. You cannot create an abstract method in a concrete base class.

**Now you could say, why not use an abstract class?**

So, when you need to achieve 100% abstraction, you need to go with `Interface`. But when you need some abstraction along with a concrete implementation, go with `abstract` class. It means.

**Example:** Lets say all your pizzas will have a base and base preparation will be the same process. However, all pizza types and toppings will vary. In this case you could create an Abstract class with an abstract method *Prepare* and a concrete method *PreparePizzaBase*.

```
public abstract class Pizza{
    // concrete method which is common to all pizzas.
    public PizzaBase PreparePizzaBase(){
        // code for pizza base preparation.
    }
    public abstract void Prepare();
}

public class DeluxePizza: Pizza{
    public void Prepare(){
        var base=PreparePizzaBase();
        // prepare deluxe pizza on pizza base.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of the interfaces is that it makes a contract between you and any other class that implement that interface which makes your code decoupled and allows expandability.

Answer (score 1):

Therese are ask really great examples.

Another, in the case of a switch statement, you no longer have the need to maintain and switch every time you want rio perform a task in a specific way.

In your pizza example, if want to make a pizza, the interface is all you need, from there each pizza takes care of it's own logic.

This helps to reduce coupling and cyclomatic complexity. You have to still implement the logic but there will be less you have to keep track of in the broader picture.

For each pizza you can then keep track of information specific to that pizza. What other pizzas have doesn't matter because only the other pizzas need to know.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to think about interfaces is to recognize what inheritance means.  If class CC inherits class C, it means both that:

1. Class CC can use any public or protected members of class C as though they were its own, and thus only needs to implement things which do not exist in the parent class.

   A reference to a CC can be passed or assigned to a routine or variable that expects a reference to a C.

Those two function of inheritance are in some sense independent; although inheritance applies both simultaneously, it is also possible to apply the second without the first.  This is useful because allowing an object to inherit members from two or more unrelated classes is much more complicated than allowing one type of thing to be substitutable for multiple types.

An interface is somewhat like an abstract base class, but with a key difference: an object which inherits a base class cannot inherit any other class.  By contrast, an object may implement an interface without affecting its ability to inherit any desired class or implement any other interfaces.

One nice feature of this (underutilized in the .net framework, IMHO) is that they make it possible to indicate declaratively the things an object can do.  Some objects, for example, will want data-source object from which they can retrieve things by index (as is possible with a List), but they won't need to store anything there.  Other routines will need a data-depository object where they can store things not by index (as with Collection.Add), but they won't need to read anything back.  Some data types will allow access by index, but won't allow writing; others will allow writing, but won't allow access by index.  Some, of course, will allow both.

If ReadableByIndex and Appendable were unrelated base classes, it would be impossible to define a type which could be passed both to things expecting a ReadableByIndex and things expecting an Appendable.  One could try to mitigate this by having ReadableByIndex or Appendable derive from the other; the derived class would have to make available public members for both purposes, but warn that some public members might not actually work.  Some of Microsoft's classes and interfaces do that, but that's rather icky.  A cleaner approach is to have interfaces for the different purposes, and then have objects implement interfaces for the things they can actually do.  If one had an interface IReadableByIndex and another interface IAppendable, classes which could do one or the other could implement the appropriate interfaces for the things they can do.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces can also be daisy chained to create yet another interface. This ability to implement multiple Interfaces give the developer the advantage of adding functionality to their classes without having to change current class functionality (SOLID Principles)

O = "Classes should be open for extension but closed for modification"

Answer (score 1):

To me an advantage/benefit of an interface is that it is more flexible than an abstract class.  Since you can only inherit 1 abstract class but you can implement multiple interfaces, changes to a system that inherits an abstract class in many places becomes problematic.  If it is inherited in 100 places, a change requires changes to all 100.  But, with the interface, you can place the new change in a new interface and just use that interface where its needed (Interface Seq. from SOLID).  Additionally, the memory usage seems like it would be less with the interface as an object in the interface example is used just once in memory despite how many places implement the interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IMachine machine = new Machine();
        machine.Run();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

class Machine : IMachine {
    private void Run() {
        Console.WriteLine("Running...");
    }
    void IMachine.Run() => Run();
}

interface IMachine
{
    void Run();
}
```

Let me describe this by a different perspective. Let’s create a story according to the example which i have shown above;

*Program, Machine and IMachine are the actors of our story. Program wants to run but it has not that ability and Machine knows how to run. Machine and IMachine are best friends but Program is not on speaking terms with Machine. So Program and IMachine make a deal and decided that IMachine will tell to Program how to run by looking Machine(like a reflector).*

*And Program learns how to run by help of IMachine.*

**Interface provides communication and developing loosely coupled projects.**

**PS:** I’ve the method of concrete class as private. My aim in here is to achieve loosely coupled by preventing accessing concrete class properties and methods, and left only allowing way to reach them via interfaces. (So i defined interfaces’ methods explicitily).

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are used to drive consistency,in a manner that is loosely coupled which makes it different to abstract class which is tightly coupled.That's why its also commonly defined as a contract.Whichever classes that implements the interface has abide to "rules/syntax" defined by the interface and there is no concrete elements within it.

I'll just give an example supported by the graphic below.

Imagine in a factory there are 3 types of machines.A rectangle machine,a triangle machine and a polygon machine.Times are competitive and you want to streamline operator training.You just want to train them in one methodology of starting and stopping machines so you have a green start button and red stop button.So now across 3 different machines you have a consistent way of starting and stopping 3 different types of machines.Now imagine these machines are classes and the classes need to have start and stop methods,how you going to drive consistency across these classes which can be very different? Interface is the answer.

[image]

A simple example to help you visualize,one might ask why not use abstract class? With an interface the objects don't have to be directly related or inherited and you can still drive consistency across different classes.

```
public interface IMachine
{
    bool Start();
    bool Stop();
}

public class Car : IMachine
{
    public bool Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car started");
        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car stopped");
        return false;
    }
}

public class Tank : IMachine
{
    public bool Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tank started");
        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tank stopped");
        return false;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var car = new Car();
        car.Start();
        car.Stop();

        var tank = new Tank();
        tank.Start();
        tank.Stop();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I am very late.. (almost nine years), but if someone wants small explanation then you can go for this:

In simple words, you use Interface when you know what an Object can do or what function we are going to implement on an object.. Example Insert,Update, and Delete.

```
interface ICRUD{
      void InsertData(); // will insert data
      void UpdateData(); // will update data
      void DeleteData(); // will delete data
}
```

**Important Note:** Interfaces are ALWAYS public.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

I share your sense that Interfaces are not necessary. Here is a quote from Cwalina pg 80 Framework Design Guidelines "I often here people saying that interfaces specify contracts. I believe this a dangerous myth. Interfaces by themselves do not specify much. ..." He and co-author Abrams managed 3 releases of .Net for Microsoft. He goes on to say that the 'contract' is "expressed" in an implementation of the class. IMHO watching this for decades, there were many people warning Microsoft that taking the engineering paradigm to the max in OLE/COM might seem good but its usefulness is more directly to hardware. Especially in a big way in the 80s and 90s getting interoperating standards codified. In our TCP/IP Internet world there is little appreciation of the hardware and software gymnastics we would jump through to get solutions 'wired up' between and among mainframes, minicomputers, and microprocessors of which PCs were just a small minority. So coding to interfaces and their protocols made computing work. And interfaces ruled. But what does solving making X.25 work with your application have in common with posting recipes for the holidays? I have been coding C++ and C# for many years and I never created one once.

Comment: Maybe you haven't created one, but I can almost guarantee you've used one (`IEnumerable`) and would be very sad if it didn't exist (LINQ extensions stop working for starters). Its pretty hard to say interfaces don't matter. I would say if you've never made one your designs could probably use some work :)

Comment: -1. Damn nonsense. What the heck this has to do with interfaces?

"In our TCP/IP Internet world there is little appreciation of the hardware and software gymnastics we would jump through to get solutions 'wired up' between and among mainframes, minicomputers, and microprocessors of which PCs were just a small minority."