# Interface on left side

Tags: c#

I know that we can't create instance of `Interface`. 
but why we can write `Interface` on left side? Are those only references of Interface
(for classes that implement this one) instead instance?

If we can't create instance of Interface, what type is `P` in this example?

```
string[] names = {"John", "Bob", "Mark"};
IEnumerable<string> P = names.Where(n => n.Contains('o'));
```

Comment: "If we can't create instance of Interface, what type is P in this example?" We don't have to know, and it is kind of the *point* of interfaces. It is a type that implements IEnumerable<string>. The precise type doesn't matter to the user.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802573/c-sharp-interfaces-whats-the-point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`P` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`

Here you are declaring the type of the local variable `P`.

`P` holds the type of `IEnumerable<string>`, and while you aren't instantiating the interface directly, you can instantiate a concrete class but simply hold a reference to the interface.

The instance returned here by the `Where()` call needs to only adhere to the contract that `IEnumerable<string>` defines.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create an instance of an interface, but you can create an instance of something that *implements* it.

What you do in your example, is simply fetch something (`p`) that is known to adhere to the contract that `IEnumerable<string>` defines.

It's easier to grasp the concept if you think of it in slightly simpler terms:

```
IBeast mrJuggles = new Tiger();
```

Mr.Juggles is now a Tiger - but also an `IBeast`. We don't explicitly create an `IBeast`, we just specify that the thing we do create, will behave as an `IBeast`, and that we therefore will be able to treat it as an `IBeast`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain this more conceptually.

> but why we can write Interface on left side?

We can, because it means: *"this object is **something** that implements this interface"*.

Interface by itself is not "something" - that's why you can't instantiate it directly - it's only a **contract**.

An interface is useless unless you define some object that is guaranteed to implement the contract expressed by it (and expose such and such methods etc.). That's the use you make of interfaces. Without this, they'd make no sense.

The contract itself is an abstract concept. It needs something to embody it - an object that fullfills it.

Have a look at the following example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App
{
    class Program
    {
        class Example
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

            public IEnumerable<string> AsEnumerable()
            {
                return list;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> foo = new Example().AsEnumerable();
            List<string> bar = (List<string>)foo;
        }
    }
}
```

You know it doesn't crash?

`IEnumerable<string>` in this line:

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = new Example().AsEnumerable();
```

actually means: *"foo is something that **we know to implement** IEnumerable".*

But it is still that *something*. It can't be only *IEnumerable* and nothing but. IEnumerable is just something that we happen to know about this something.

Otherwise we couldn't cast it back to `List<string>`, could we? (This is actually a common caveat in C#, because the caller could do this cast, therefore gaining access to `Add` and `Remove` methods and messing with the contents of our list even though we intended them not to. It's encapsulation leakage).

In other words: `IEnumerable<string>` is **the way we look at this object**.

**EDIT:**

As @Kjartan suggested, you could verify this all like so:

```
bool isFooIEnumerable = foo is IEnumerable<string>; // it's true 
bool isBarIEnumerable = bar is IEnumerable<string>; // true again
bool isFooList = foo is List<string>; // yup. true
bool isBarList = bar is List<string>; // true all the way
```

Comment: Actually, I always though of it the other way around; `foo` is an `IEnumerable`, because it has precisely the attributes required to be defined as one. That does not mean it can't be something else too.

Comment: @Kjartan I rephrased.

Comment: Better. :) PS: If you add a clause like `var isFooIEnumerable<string> = (foo is IEnumerable<string>)` and `var isBarList<string> = (bar is List<string>)`, and both the other way around too, you'll get `true` in all 4 cases, and your code might make the point even clearer. :)

Answer (score 1):

On the left hand side you declare the type of variable.

`IEnumerable<string> stringEnumerator`

You tell to the compiler that from this moment under value `stringEnumerator` can be presented a null reference or reference to object that is a string enumerator.

So when you have an expression like

`IEnumerable<string> P = names.where(n => n.Contains('o'));`

You say, create a variable `p` that will represent `IEnumerable<string>` and assign to it result of `names.where(n => n.Contains('o'));`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, if the left-hand side part in an assignment is typed as an interface type, it means that that left-hand side part (variable or such) is a reference to any instance of a class that implements said interface.

In the presented example, `P` is a reference to an instance of some internal framework class that implements `IEnumerable<string>`. As it is some internal class (presumeably hidden within the implementation of [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), we do not even have access to the class name (and thus could not declare any variable of that type). In fact, Microsoft might be changing the actual class that is returned by [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with every .NET version. However, neither would we notice that, nor do we have to care, as all we need to know is that *something* that implements `IEnumerable<string>` will be returned, hence we also just declare the variable `P` as referencing *something* that implements `IEnumerable<string>` rather than as a concrete class.