# Simplification of prefix notation

Tags: javascript, prefix-notation

I am working on a Kattis [problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/polish), where I am supposed to take the input in prefix notation, simplify it and return it in prefix notation as well.
These are the examples of inputs and outputs:

```
Sample Input 1                    Sample Output 1
+ 3 4                             Case 1: 7
- x x                             Case 2: - x x
* - 6 + x -6 - - 9 6 * 0 c        Case 3: * - 6 + x -6 - 3 * 0 c
```

I have written this piece of code, and if I run it with this kind of input data, I get exactly the same output as stated above. Yet, I get wrong answer from Kattis.

What is it that I am doing wrong here? 
It is frustrating since you get no debugging hints.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
const operatorsFunctions = {
    '+': (a, b) => a + b,
    '-': (a, b) => a - b,
    '*': (a, b) => a * b,
    '/': (a, b) => a / b,
};

let lineNumber = 0;

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    const mathExpression = line.split(' ');
    lineNumber += 1;
    let result = [];
    let stack = [];

    for (let i = mathExpression.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!isNaN(mathExpression[i])) {
            stack.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
        } else if (operators.includes(mathExpression[i])){
            if (!stack.length) {
                result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
            }
            if (stack.length === 1) {
                result.unshift(stack[0]);
                result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
                stack = [];
            }
            if (stack.length > 1) {
                const sum = operatorsFunctions[mathExpression[i]](Number(stack[0]), Number(stack[1]))
                stack.splice(0, 2, sum);
                if (i === 0) {
                    result.unshift(...stack);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (stack.length) {
                result.unshift(...stack);
                stack = [];
            }
            result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
        }
    }
    const text = `Case ${lineNumber}: ${result.join(' ')}`;
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as 'simplification'. I would describe it as 'evaluation of constant subexpressions'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update:** even though it's far away from perfect, the improved version of the code under <sup>[2]</sup> passes all tests on Kattis. See my concerns below.

There are several issues with your original code <sup>[1]</sup>:

- For the input `+ / 1 2 1` your code yields: `1` instead of `1.5`.

  The reason is your usage of `parseInt` on stack values which has the effect that floats are converted to an integer by ignoring the fractional part of said number.

  Examples:

  - `parseInt(1/2) === 0`
  - `parseInt(2/3) === 0`

  *Solution*: replace all occurrences of `parseInt` with `Number`
- For the input `1` your code yields:  instead of `1`

  The reason for this is that the `stack` is only appended to `result` if the code is processing a variable or an operator

  *Solution*:  do `result.unshift(...stack)` after the `for`-loop.

Find the improved version of the code under <sup>[2]</sup>. This version passes all Kattis tests.

**BUT**: I can not guarantee that there are no other bugs. Solving the puzzle the way you started it, feels so unnatural and unnecessarily complicated. For this reason I would suggest abandoning this approach entirely. The problem with the chosen solution is that it tries to simplify the expression while parsing it from right to left. The whole point behind the prefix notation is that you can simplify expressions easily while parsing from left to right by always reading and processing one symbol at the time. You will find a much simpler solution to the problem if you do that. The key idea here is that you need a function `readNextSymbol` which reads a symbol and either:

- (recursive step) if it the symbol is an operator: calls the operator functions which uses `readNextSymbol` to fetch its arguments.
- (base case) if the symbol is a variable or constant: casts and returns the symbol.

---

## <sup>[1] original code</sup>

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
const operatorsFunctions = {
    '+': (a, b) => a + b,
    '-': (a, b) => a - b,
    '*': (a, b) => a * b,
    '/': (a, b) => a / b,
};

let lineNumber = 0;

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    const mathExpression = line.split(' ');
    lineNumber += 1;
    let result = [];
    let stack = [];

    for (let i = mathExpression.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!isNaN(mathExpression[i])) {
            stack.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
        } else if (operators.includes(mathExpression[i])){
            if (!stack.length) {
                result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
            }
            if (stack.length === 1) {
                result.unshift(stack[0]);
                result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
                stack = [];
            }
            if (stack.length > 1) {
                const sum = operatorsFunctions[mathExpression[i]](parseInt(stack[0]), parseInt(stack[1]))
                stack.splice(0, 2, sum);
                if (i === 0) {
                    result.unshift(...stack);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (stack.length) {
                result.unshift(...stack);
                stack = [];
            }
            result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
        }
    }
    const text = `Case ${lineNumber}: ${result.join(' ')}`;
    console.log(text);
});
```

## <sup>[2] working code</sup>

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
const operatorsFunctions = {
    '+': (a, b) => a + b,
    '-': (a, b) => a - b,
    '*': (a, b) => a * b,
    '/': (a, b) => a / b,
};

function parse(line) {
    const mathExpression = line.split(' ');
    let result = [];
    let stack = [];

    for (let i = mathExpression.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!isNaN(mathExpression[i])) {
            stack.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
        } else if (operators.includes(mathExpression[i])){
            if (!stack.length) {
                result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
            }
            if (stack.length === 1) {
                result.unshift(stack[0]);
                result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
                stack = [];
            }
            if (stack.length > 1) {
                const sum = operatorsFunctions[mathExpression[i]](
                  Number(stack[0]), 
                  Number(stack[1])
                )
                stack.splice(0, 2, sum);
            }
        } else {
            if (stack.length) {
                result.unshift(...stack);
                stack = [];
            }
            result.unshift(mathExpression[i]);
        }
    }
    result.unshift(...stack);
    return result.join(' ');
}


let lineNumber = 0;
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  lineNumber += 1;
  let answer = parse(line);
  console.log(`Case ${lineNumber}: ${answer}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally echo the sentiment in [Ente's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59116531/1541563) after reviewing the code provided in the question:

> I would suggest abandoning this approach entirely.

After careful consideration of feedback in the comments below, I've boiled down my object-oriented approach to a conventional [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) style, and a more functional [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) style.

The two styles share:

- a common [interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6802573/1541563),

  ```
  interface Expression {
    isConstant(void): boolean;
    toString(void): string;
    simplify(void): Expression;
  }
  ```
- two types `Binary` and `Nullary`, which implement the interface `Expression` and represent expressions of [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) two or zero respectively,
- a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of operators to binary functions,

  ```
  const operators = new Map([
    ['+', (a, b) => a + b],
    ['-', (a, b) => a - b],
    ['*', (a, b) => a * b],
    ['/', (a, b) => a / b]
  ]);
  ```
- and a static method.

  ```
  function parse (tokens) {
    const token = tokens.shift();

    if (!operators.has(token)) {
      return new Nullary(token);
    }

    const a = parse(tokens);
    const b = parse(tokens);

    return new Binary(token, a, b);
  }
  ```

The class style uses runtime [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1031273/1541563) and defines the classes `Binary` and `Nullary`:

```
class Binary {
  constructor (op, a, b) {
    this.op = op;
    this.operands = [a, b];
    this.f = operators.get(op);
  }

  isConstant () {
    return this.operands.every(e => e.isConstant());
  }
  toString () {
    return `${this.op} ${this.operands.join(' ')}`;
  }
  simplify () {
    const args = this.operands.map(e => e.simplify());

    return args.every(e => e.isConstant())
    ? new Nullary(`${this.f(...args.map(Number))}`)
    : new Binary(this.op, ...args);
  }
}

class Nullary {
  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  isConstant () { return !isNaN(this.value); }
  toString () { return this.value; }
  simplify () { return this; }
}
```

The closure style defines two functions `Binary()` and `Nullary()`, each of which returns an object that implements the `Expression` interface:

```
function Binary (op, a, b) {
  const operands = [a, b];
  const f = operators.get(op);

  return {
    isConstant: () => operands.every(e => e.isConstant()),
    toString: () => `${op} ${operands.join(' ')}`,
    simplify: () => {
      const args = operands.map(e => e.simplify());

      return args.every(e => e.isConstant())
      ? Nullary(`${f(...args.map(Number))}`)
      : Binary(op, ...args)
    }
  };
}

function Nullary (value) {
  const self = {
    isConstant: () => !isNaN(value),
    toString: () => value,
    simplify: () => self
  };

  return self;
}
```

<sup>Note that the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator used in `parse()` is not necessary for calling the static functions defined in the closure style above.</sup>

Finally, both of these read input and write output with the same boilerplate to call `parse()` and `expression.simplify()`:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

let lineNo = 0;

rl.on('line', line => {
  const tokens = line.split(/\s+/g);
  const expression = parse(tokens);

  console.log(`Case ${++lineNo}: ${expression.simplify()}`);
});
```

<sub>Thanks [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for your [feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59035284/1541563#comment104469363_59119178), which inspired me to write a closure-based approach.</sub>

Comment: I would recommend having a separate `simplified` method returning a new `Expression` or a number/string, instead of mixing the simplification logic into the `toString` method.

Comment: Also you might want to consider representing literals with an `Expression` instance themselves (maybe `operator = ""`, `fn = parseInt`, `operands = [token]`)? Then you could make `parse` and `simplified` return always an expression, and make `isConstant` an instance method instead of a static one.

Comment: @Bergi I actually initially tried doing that but it felt too over-engineered and I decided that this was a sufficient level of abstraction for a challenge like this.

Comment: That second part I do like, I'll see if I can work that into the solution in a way that feels natural.

Comment: The whole OOP approach feels a bit over-engineered to me (though I like its clarity), but if going for it I'd still do it properly :-)

Comment: While this approach deserves an upvote for overall quality, I don't think PN/RPN expressions need expression trees to be evaluated. The whole point is to be able to parse left-to-right (or right-to-left) without an AST (as it's already preparsed). You only need a stack. Anyway, good job.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Not exactly what I thought of (I'd kept a single class for simplicity…), but have an upvote for going the extra mile :-) Nit: `UnaryExpression` should be `NullaryExpression`.

Comment: @Bergi `nullary` - `having the arity of zero`. Learned something new, I'm happy to change naming to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The steps to solve this problem are straightforward:

- start from the end of the line
- if you spot pattern: operator, number, number

  - replace these three items with the result of evaluation of the items

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const ops = ["+", "-", "/", "*"];
let lineNumber = 0;

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    lineNumber += 1;
    let exp = line.split(" ");
    for (let i = exp.length - 2; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if (ops.includes(exp[i])) {
            if (![exp[i+1], exp[i+2]].map(Number).some(Number.isNaN)) {
                exp.splice(i, 3, eval([exp[i+1], exp[i], exp[i+2]].join(" ")));
            } else { // a letter detected - we can safely skip two items
               i -= 2;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(`Case ${lineNumber}: ${exp.join(" ")}`);
});
```

And if someone fancy longer but well-described functional code with reducers and higher-order functions, immutability* and referential transparency* which is great for unit testing, here it is:

```
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

let lineNumber = 0;
rl.on("line", line => {
  lineNumber += 1;
  let tokens = line.split(" ");
  let simplified = tokens.reduceRight(simplify(), []);

  console.log(`Case ${lineNumber}: ${simplified.join(" ")}`);
});

function simplify() {
  const operations = {
    "+": (a, b) => a + b,
    "-": (a, b) => a - b,
    "*": (a, b) => a * b,
    "/": (a, b) => a / b
  };
  const skip = { val: 2 };
  const doWork = createDoWork(skip, operations);
  return (simplified, token) => {
    if (skip.val) {
      skip.val--;
      return [token, ...simplified];
    }
    return doWork(simplified, token);
  };
}

function createDoWork(skip, operations) {
  const isOperator = createIsOperator(operations);
  const replaceWithEvaluation = createReplaceWithEvaluation(operations);
  return (simplified, token) => {
    if (isOperator(token)) {
      if (firstTwoAreNumbers(simplified)) {
        return replaceWithEvaluation(token, simplified);
      }
      skip.val = 2;
    }
    return [token, ...simplified];
  };
}

function createIsOperator(operations) {
  const operationTokens = Object.keys(operations);
  return token => operationTokens.includes(token);
}

function firstTwoAreNumbers(arr) {
  return !arr
    .slice(0, 2)
    .map(Number)
    .some(Number.isNaN);
}

function createReplaceWithEvaluation(operations) {
  return (operator, simplified) => {
    const [n1, n2, ...rest] = simplified;
    const evaluation = operations[operator](+n1, +n2);
    return [evaluation, ...rest];
  };
}
```

*<sup>* there's a small optimization that speeds the code up to 3 times but also makes part of the code impure. I'll leave the task of refactoring it for a curious reader ;)</sup>*

Comment: I'd avoid using tagged template literal syntax for calling normal functions (when not participating in code golf challenge)

Comment: @Bergi sure, I'd not use it in production but since they look great I like to use them for presentational purposes :)

Comment: They might look great to you (I have to disagree there), but I think they're wrong: they rely on the method to cast the array argument to a string, which will probably fail with most other functions. Using this style in code presentations will lead to other developers adopting it, eventually causing a bad practice to make it into prod.

Comment: @Bergi okay, I'll change it for the sake of promoting good practices and as a bonus add a small optimization ;)

Answer (score 1):

*This most likely won't pass the Kattis test suite but I just wanted to share another approach*

---

I would first turn an expression into a data structure:

```js
tokenize('+ x + 10 20');
//=> ['+', 'x', ['+', '10', '20']]
```

Why? It allows us to recursively interpret *"O A B"* expressions:

```js
const simplify_expr = ([o, a, b]) =>
  interpret(
    [ o
    , is_expr(a) ? simplify_expr(a) : evaluate(a)
    , is_expr(b) ? simplify_expr(b) : evaluate(b)
    ]);

simplify_expr(['+', 'x', ['+', '10', '20']]);
//=> ['+', 'x', 30]
```

Given the following simplification procedure:

> The simplification procedure is just replacing subexpressions that contain no variables with their values wherever possible.

Then the `interpret` function can be written as follows:

```js
const interpret = ([o, a, b]) =>
    typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number' ? [o, a, b]
  : o === '*' ? a * b
  : o === '/' ? a / b
  : o === '+' ? a + b
              : a - b;

interpret(['+', 10, 20]);
//=> 30
```

---

#### How do I turn an expression into a data structure?

Split a string:

```js
'+ x + 10 + 20 30'.split(' ')
//=> ['+', 'x', '+', '10', '+', '20', '30']
```

Then recurse from right to left until you've grouped all expressions by groups of three:

```js
['+', 'x', '+', '10', '+', '20', '30']     // length > 3
['+', 'x', '+', '10', ['+', '20', '30']]   // length > 3
['+', 'x', ['+', '10', ['+', '20', '30']]] // length 3 stop!
```

Possible implementation:

```js
const group_expr = xs =>
  xs.length <= 3
    ? xs
    : is_expr(xs.slice(-3))
      ? group_expr(
          [ ...xs.slice(0, -3)
          , xs.slice(-3)
          ])
      : group_expr(
          [ ...xs.slice(0, -4)
          , xs.slice(-4, -1)
          , ...xs.slice(-1)
          ]);

const tokenize = str =>
  group_expr(str.split(' '));
```

---

#### Full working example

⚠️This uses `Array.prototype.flat` which isn't supported in Edge.

```js
const evaluate = x =>
  Number(x) == x
    ? Number(x)
    : x;

const is_expr = x =>
  Array.isArray(x) &&
  ( x[0] === '*' ||
    x[0] === '/' ||
    x[0] === '+' ||
    x[0] === '-' );

const group_expr = xs =>
  xs.length <= 3
    ? xs
    : is_expr(xs.slice(-3))
      ? group_expr(
          [ ...xs.slice(0, -3)
          , xs.slice(-3)
          ])
      : group_expr(
          [ ...xs.slice(0, -4)
          , xs.slice(-4, -1)
          , ...xs.slice(-1)
          ]);

const tokenize = str =>
  group_expr(str.split(' '));

const interpret = ([o, a, b]) =>
    typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number' ? [o, a, b]
  : o === '*' ? a * b
  : o === '/' ? a / b
  : o === '+' ? a + b
              : a - b;

const simplify_expr = ([o, a, b]) =>
  interpret(
    [ o
    , is_expr(a) ? simplify_expr(a) : evaluate(a)
    , is_expr(b) ? simplify_expr(b) : evaluate(b)
    ]);

const simplify = str => {
  const expr = simplify_expr(tokenize(str));
  return Array.isArray(expr)
    ? expr.flat(Infinity).join(' ')
    : String(expr);
};

console.log(simplify('+ 3 4'));
console.log(simplify('- x x'));
console.log(simplify('* - 6 + x -6 - - 9 6 * 0 c'));
console.log(simplify('+ x + 10 + 20 30'));
```