# Benefit of AddSingleton(S, T) instead of AddSingleton(T)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

What is the benefit of using `services.AddSingleton<SomeService, SomeServiceImplementation>()` instead of `services.AddSingleton<SomeServiceImplementation>()` ?

For example i've got an sample Interface

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
   void DoSomething();
}
```

And a Sample-Class:

```
class SampleClass : ISampleInterface
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    console.write("hi");
  }
}
```

No i do `services.AddSingleton<SampleClass>()`

Why or when to use `services.AddSingleton<ISampleInterface, SampleClass>()` ?

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: _"Why or when to use"_ frankly, always with rare exceptions. If you do, then you can inject the interface to other services. And that decouples the dependency. You could then easily swap in another implementation of that interface with one part of one line of code in need for change. It also enables for easier mocking in unit tests.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this question: interfaces - What's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802573/interfaces-whats-the-point) - It's not 100% identical, but this question seems to be asking the same question in a roundabout way.

Comment: @John, no. Its not the same Question. I know what a Interface is. I just dont see a benefit of the function .AddService(T,S) instead of .AddService(T)

Comment: If you didn't have `.AddService(T,S)`, how would you register an implementation as its interface?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_

Instead of: services.AddSingleton<SampleClass>()
when SamplesClass:ISampleInterface

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`services.AddSingleton<SampleInterface, SampleClass>()` allows you to register different implementations for the same interface without modifying the rest of your code.

**Change implementations with minimal effort**

Suppose you have an `ILogger` interface and implementation that log eg to the browser's console or send the log entry to different services eg `ConsoleLogger`, `MyServiceLogger` or `PrometheusLogger`. If you registered only the implementation, with eg `services.AddSingleton<ConsoleLogger>()` you'd have to change all of your classes each time you changed a logger implementation.

You'd have to go to each page and change

```
@inject ConsoleLogger logger;
```

to

```
@inject MyServiceLogger logger;
```

Forget about specifying the logger at runtime too. You'd have to deploy the application each time you wanted to use a new logging service.

By registering the interface and a specific implementation, all of your classes can keep using `ILogger<T>` and never know that the implementation has changed.

**Implementation selection at runtime**

You could even change the implementation at runtime, based on environment variables, configuration, or any other logic you want, eg :

```
if (app.IsDevelopment)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ILogger,ConsoleLogger>();
}
else
{
    services.AddSingleton<ILogger,MyServiceLogger>();
}
```

**Unit Testing**

In unit tests you could use a null logger - in fact the Logging middleware has a [NullLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nulllogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class just for this reason, in the core Abstractions package.

Or you could wrap your test framework's output methods into an `ILogger` implementation and use that, without modifying the code. xUnit for example uses the [ITestOutputHelper](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output) interface for this. You could create an `XUnitlogger` that forwards calls to this interface:

```
public class XUnitLogger:ILogger
{
   private readonly ITestOutputHelper _output;
   public XUnitLogger(ITestOutputHelper output)
   {
       _output=output;
   }
   ...
   void Log(...)
   {
       _output.WriteLine(...);
   }
}
```