# VBA Implements / Inheritance

Tags: excel, vba, interface

I'm having a hard time understanding and working with `Implements` and I'm failing to see why this is of any use if Inheritance isn't supported with VBA.

I'm testing the code below and I keep getting the error:

> Compile Error:
>
> Object module needs to implement '~' for interface '~'

**Interface:**  `ITransmission`

```
Option Explicit

Public pVENDOR As String

Public Property Get VENDOR() As String
End Property
Public Property Let VENDOR(ByVal value As String)
End Property
```

**Base Class:** `cASN`

```
Option Explicit
Implements ITransmission

Private Property Let ITransmission_pVENDOR(ByVal value As String)
   pVENDOR = value
End Property

Private Property Get ITransmission_pVENDOR() As String
   ITransmission_pVENDOR = pVENDOR
End Property
```

**Unit Test Method:** `mUnitTesting`

```
Private Sub Test_cASN()

   Dim foo As cASN

   Set foo = New cASN

   foo.VENDOR = "Test"

End Sub
```

Still very new to Implements and it is something I want to learn, and I've done a fair amount of research into it.

**Question 1:**

Why am I getting an error message when I try to unit test this?

**Question 2:**

What is the real benefit here, if inheritance isn't supported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the Implements in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement `pVENDOR` but not the two `VENDOR` properties.

I'm assuming you want the interface to be a get/let of the `VENDOR` property.

Your `Public pVENDOR As String` looks like a backing field for this property, as an Interface cannot include an implementation then its not needed.

The Interface should look like:

```
Public Property Get VENDOR() As String
End Property

Public Property Let VENDOR(ByVal value As String)
End Property
```

Then when you implement it:

```
Implements ITransmission

Private pVENDOR As String '// local implementation detail

Public Property Let ITransmission_VENDOR(ByVal value As String)
    pVENDOR = value
End Property

Public Property Get ITransmission_VENDOR() As String
    ITransmission_VENDOR = pVENDOR
End Property
```

And to test:

```
Private Sub Test_cASN()

   Dim foo As cASN

   Set foo = New cASN

   foo.ITransmission_VENDOR = "Test"

End Sub
```

**What is the real benefit here**

[How will I know when to create an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444245/how-will-i-know-when-to-create-an-interface)

[The point of an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971326/the-point-of-an-interface)

Comment: This is great thanks! I found this as well... Is this an optimal work around to inheritance as well? https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2225071&seqNum=2

Comment: Also, to make this clear... to my understanding an `Interface` is essentially a template that a class would have to follow? So, if I had two unique classes that implement the `ITransmission` interface, these two classes **MUST** include these Get/Let properties, which is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes... the must implement all the methods of the interface class.