# Where and why do we use an interface ? c#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.net Interface explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021777/net-interface-explanation)

Where and why do we use an interface ?, c#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=interface%20[.net]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444245/

Answer (score 1):

Introducing yourself to design patterns should help.

In 2 words - when we need to abstract a type's contract from its implementation.