# Controller with same structure not working using an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, datacontext

I have created 8 models and controllers respectively for my Project using the same structure, however now this structure is not working.  It is giving me this error:

> The current type, HelpDesk.Contracts.Repositories.IRepositoryBase`1[HelpDesk.Model.Knowledgebase], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Here is my interface:

```
    namespace HelpDesk.Contracts.Repositories
{
    public interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity>
     where TEntity : class
    {
        void Commit();
        void Delete(object id);
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(object filter);
        TEntity GetById(object id);
        TEntity GetFullObject(object id);
        System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity> GetPaged(int top = 20, int skip = 0, object orderBy = null, object filter = null);
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace HelpDesk.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class KnowledgebaseController : Controller
    {

        private DataContext db = new DataContext();

        IRepositoryBase<Knowledgebase> knowledgebases;

        public KnowledgebaseController(IRepositoryBase<Knowledgebase> knowledgebases)
        {
            this.knowledgebases = knowledgebases;
        }

public ActionResult ChooseSearchView()
        {
            string r = Session["LoggedUserRole"].ToString();

            if (r == "Technician")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("TechKnowledgebaseSearch");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("UserKnowledgebaseSearch");
            };

        }
```

My DataContext:

```
namespace HelpDesk.Contracts.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// you can either pass the NAME of a connection string (e.g. from a web.
        /// ), and explicitly i
        ///  </summary>
        public DataContext() : base("HelpDesk")
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// any entity to be persisted must be declared here.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Knowledgebase> Knowledgebases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Problem> Problems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TicketNote> TicketNotes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TicketStatus> TicketStatuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TicketSubscription> TicketSubscriptions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Here is the repositorybase:

```
 namespace HelpDesk.Contracts.Repositories
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : HelpDesk.Contracts.Repositories.IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal DataContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public RepositoryBase(DataContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return dbSet;
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetPaged(int top = 20, int skip = 0, object orderBy = null, object filter = null)
        {
            return null; // need to override in order to implement specific filtering and ordering
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(object filter)
        {
            return null; //need to override in order to implement specific filtering
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetFullObject(object id)
        {
            return null; //need to override in order to implement specific obect graph.
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
                dbSet.Attach(entity);

            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entity = dbSet.Find(id);

        }

        public virtual void Commit()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Here I have a similar structured Controller that works just fine and another 7 like that:

```
namespace HelpDesk.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class RoleController : Controller
    {

        private DataContext db = new DataContext();

        IRepositoryBase<Role> roles;

        public RoleController(IRepositoryBase<Role> roles)
        {
            this.roles = roles;
        }
```

The Exception is thrown when I click on this link:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Knowledgebase", "ChooseSearchView", "Knowledgebase")</li>
```

Comment: Is your concrete class for IRepositoryBase parameterless and at what point was the exception thrown?

Comment: The Exception is thrown when I hit the button that calls the ChooseSearchView Method

Comment: Here is the button (or link) that I click that creates the exception:

<li>@Html.ActionLink("Knowledgebase", "ChooseSearchView", "Knowledgebase")</li>

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of your IRepositoryBase. You need not expose all the methods. I just need to see the constructor and the class head definition.

Comment: I added the RepositoryBase class to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80679/discussion-between-oluwafemi-and-djblois).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your KnowledgebaseController constructor to this:

```
public KnowledgebaseController()
        {
            this.knowledgebases = new RepositoryBase<Knowledgebase>(db);
        }
```

and remove **abstract** from the `RepositoryBase<TEntity>` class in order to make it instantiable.

**Please note: This is just a quick fix**. To implement a much solid architecture which facilitates easy unit testing and loosely coupled classes, I would suggest you implement a unit of work. Follow this link [Repository Pattern and Unit of Work with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an interface, you have to instantiate a class that implements that interface.

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase
{
    public RepositoryBase<T>()
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

Then instantiate your concrete class with that type

```
IRepositoryBase<Knowledgebase> knowledgebases = new RepositoryBase<Knowledgebase>();
```

Read more about interfaces and instantiation here: [Using Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151993/2461203)

Comment: I do not understand your answer - where am I supposed to put that.  I am only programming MVC for a month now.

Comment: This isn't particular to MVC, but OOP as a whole. Your controller does not implement the interface, so there is no point in making it the same structure. You should create a separate class called `RepositoryBase` that *implements* the interface (first code block above) that has the structure of the interface, and then in your `RepositoryController` define your variable like the second code block.

Comment: I do have a RepositoryBase, I just did not post the code.  Should I post that too?

Comment: I added my RepositoryBase class to my question

Comment: In your `KnowledgebaseController`, change your `IRepositoryBase<Knowledgebase> knowledgebases;` to the second line of code I put in my answer.

Comment: I did and I received this compile error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface

Comment: What class to you have that implements that abstract class? You need to have a class that implements IRepositoryBase<Knowledgebase>. Your other controller is looking for something that implements IRepositoryBase<Role>. You must have an implementation for that if they are working. What is different between that implementation and the implementation of the class that implements IRepositoryBase<Knowledgebase>?

Comment: You need another constructor in your `RepositoryBase` - something like `public RepositoryBase<T>() {}`