# C# Interface as DataType

Tags: c#

Hi guys I'm trying to learn some interface. I got the basic knowledge about it, that is a contract for a class. I am a bit confused now about Interface being a data type.

Question:
What is the Purpose of using an Interface as a Data Type?

Ex.

```
IEnumerable Folders {get;}
```

or

```
IComparable Compare {get;}
```

If I'm correct then `IEnumerable` is also an Interface.
Where is the Value Type saved (if there is any)?

Comment: this will give you good idea - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151959/using-interface-variables

Answer (score 7):

It means that the data type can reference any object of a  class implementing the interface.

`IEnumerable thing = new List();` works

`IEnumerable thing = new Collection();` also works

`IEnumerable thing = new HashSet();` also works

In any case, **you don't need to know the exact type** that is actually assigned to your object, **you just want any type that implements the contract**

For example, all `IEnumerator` implement `GetEnumerator()` which allow you to use `foreach`

`foreach (var elem in thing)` will work whatever type is thing, it just needs to implement IEnumerator.