# What does exactly happpen when I cast an object reference variable to Interface

Tags: c#, oop

```
//Main method
Belle jhbh = new();
IOpera kujb = (IOpera)jhbh;

interface IOpera {

}

interface IFire:IOpera {

}


class Belle :fff,IFire {


}
```

Can you please tell me, how does the casting work?
To me the following two variants would do the same thing:
1. IOpera kujb = (IOpera)jhbh;
2. IOpera kujb = jhbh;

I mean, at the end of the day It is `kujb` that decides what member is accessible and what is not, right.
and since, In both cases, `kujb` points to the same object, what is the point of casting then? 
I think I am getting something horribly wrong.

Comment: The point of casting is either to pass or store it as the interface type, or to access [explicit interface implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class Belle` and `interface IOpera` are:

- two different types
- the point of the interface is that [it guarantees that what ever implements it will provide the methods declared within it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151993/1646240).

> what is the point of casting then?

As these are two different types.

> IOpera kujb = (IOpera)jhbh;

[As msdn says about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions):

> These kinds of operations are called **type conversions**. In C#, you can
> perform the following kinds of conversions:
>
> **Implicit conversions**: No special syntax is required because the
> conversion always succeeds and no data will be lost. Examples include
> conversions from smaller to larger integral types, and conversions
> from derived classes to base classes.
>
> **Explicit conversions (casts)**: Explicit conversions require a cast
> expression. Casting is required when information might be lost in the
> conversion, or when the conversion might not succeed for other
> reasons. Typical examples include numeric conversion to a type that
> has less precision or a smaller range, and conversion of a base-class
> instance to a derived class.
>
> **User-defined conversions**: User-defined conversions are performed by
> special methods that you can define to enable explicit and implicit
> conversions between custom types that do not have a base class–derived
> class relationship. For more information, see User-defined conversion
> operators.
>
> **Conversions with helper classes**: To convert between non-compatible
> types, such as integers and System.DateTime objects, or hexadecimal
> strings and byte arrays, you can use the System.BitConverter class,
> the System.Convert class, and the Parse methods of the built-in
> numeric types, such as Int32.Parse. For more information, see [How to
> convert a byte array to an int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int), [How to convert a string to a number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number), and [How to convert between hexadecimal strings and numeric > types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types).

**UPDATE:**

Upcasting can be done without explicit cast. So this is an example of implicit cast:

```
Engineer engineer = new Engineer();
IEmployee employee = engineer;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for tour answer, can you give me an example where I would upcast to an interface?

Comment: Thank you very much, just did that :), so this leads me into thinking that there is an implicit conversion operator between the implementing class and the Interface. I am correct right?

Comment: @Jason9789 thanks! Yeah, you are right! I've updated my reply. Please, see my updated answer