# Cast from ConcurrentDictionary to IDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrentdictionary

Does a cast from `ConcurrentDictionary` to `IDictionary` cut off the thread-safe implementation, since `IDictionary` doesn't have `GetOrAdd` and `AddOrUpdate` methods ?

Comment: How do you mean "cut", precisely?  Does it remove it from `ConcurrentDictionary`?    No.  Is it available from the `IDictionary` interface?  No.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: He means that, if you cast to `IDictionary`, does it make the resulting object thread-unsafe?  In other words, does it turn it into an ordinary dictionary?

Comment: Will it still be thread-safe?  Yes insomuch as it can be without those operations.  That is, if you need an atomic `GetOrAdd()` you'll be out of luck.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare `GetOrAdd()` is not atomic. The delegate is executed outside the internal lock to prevent deadlocks. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx

Comment: @mikez: Yes, sorry, atomic was the wrong choice of words.  My bad.  I meant to say that the actual Add() if it doesn't exist would be synchronized so only one competitor actually does the Add(), but as you correctly point out from the MSDN multiple simultaneous callers may execute the delegate and end up generating an un-needed item which is ignored.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The resulting object will still be a concurrent dictionary. The calls like Add or Remove use the underlying implementation TryAdd and TryRemove  (which are thread-safe). Casting an object to a different type doesn't change the object itself.

Also, for clarification, you could use tools like ILSpy to see what's the implementation of default IDictionary methods and whether they'll be still thread-safe.

Comment: You can also look at the MSDN documentation for ConcurrentDictionary's implementations of the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Answer (score 6):

`IDictionary` is just an interface.  If you cast to it, the result is an implementation of ConcurrentDictionary, missing the `GetOrAdd` and `AddOrUpdate` methods.

Presumably, you can still use the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267253.aspx) property and the  [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx) and [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy.aspx) methods (in lieu of the `GetOrAdd` and `AddOrUpdate`) methods, and your casted object will still be thread-safe (since the underlying implementation is a `ConcurrentDictionary`).

Answer (score 1):

The interface doesn't affect the implementation. It just doesn't exposed some of `ConcurrentDictionary`'s methods.

You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122883/interfaces-why-cant-i-seem-to-grasp-them) helpful in understanding interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It would be like looking at big `ConcurrentDictionary` object through `IDictionary` shaped keyhole - you could only see `IDictionary` shape but it would still be `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

When a [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) is exposed as an [`IDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2), it is thread-safe in a very limited sense: the consistence of its internal state is guaranteed. No undocumented exceptions will be thrown, and no values are going to emerge out of the blue that were never added to the dictionary. But in a broader sense of the term, taking into account how the dictionary interacts with the rest of the application and how meaningful are the data that it contains, it's unlikely to be thread-safe. The reason is that the `IDictionary<K,V>` interface doesn't expose the specialized atomic APIs that make the `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` suitable for multithreaded usage. Without these APIs, many common operations become impossible.

For example let's say that you have a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>`, and you want to increment the value of the key `"A"`, or, if the key does not exist, add it with the value `1`. The correct API to use is the [`AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate):

```
dictionary.AddOrUpdate("A", 1, (_, existing) => existing + 1);
```

Without this API, you are stuck. By using only the members of the `IDictionary<string, int>` interface, the best you can do is this:

```
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("A", out int existing))
    dictionary["A"] = existing + 1;
else
    dictionary.Add("A", 1);
```

...which is irreparably flawed because the operation is not atomic. Another thread might change the value of the key, between the calls to the `TryGetValue` and to the set indexer. So the final value for the key `"A"` might not be equal to the number of times that it was (supposedly) incremented. There is no way to fix this race condition. The `IDictionary<K,V>` interface was simply not designed for multithreaded usage.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer no.

You are manipulating an object through an interface and hence still using the concrete implementation. You are not losing any functionality nor its methods. They are just not available.

On the side note, you need an explicit cast when downcasting, no need for an explicit cast when upcasting - always safe to do so.

Comment: sorry but ConcurrentDictionary add two new methods and hide others, so its implementation could add thread-safe only for the new methods, and not for the hidden methods. MSDN documentation doesn't clarify it, so I asked it. But after I read the best comments and I took a look at ConcurrentDictionary prototype I saw what it doens't extends Dictionary, and this reassured me that is improbable that casting it to IDictionary would indirectly use the extended version Dictionary.